# Adding Python to PATH on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, path

I've been trying to add the Python path to the command line on Windows, yet no matter the method I try, nothing seems to work. I've used the `set` command, I've tried adding it through the Edit Environment Variables prompt, etc.

Furthermore, if I run the set command on the command line it lists this.

```
python = c:\python27
```

Yet it still doesn't recognize the Python command.

Reading the documentation, and various other sources haven't seemed to help.

Just to clarify further, I've appended the path of the Python executable to PATH in the Edit Environment prompt. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does the executable lie within that directory? Isnt there some bin directory within that?

Comment: @anirudh4444 No, its in that directory...

Comment: You can get both `GUI` and `Command Line` option from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38141751/5409601

Comment: Whilst not valid to you, with the Python 3.6 Windows Installer (and potentially earlier versions) you can choose to "Customise" your installation and there is a checkbox to add Python to your path.

Comment: This clean article on [how to add python to environment](https://semicolon.dev/windows/how-to-add-python-to-environment-variables) vars helped me

Answer (score 276):

1. Hold <kbd>Win</kbd> and press <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
2. Click Advanced System Settings.
3. Click Environment Variables.
4. Append `;C:\python27` to the `Path` variable.
5. Restart Command Prompt.

Comment: Yeah, I've already done that. Sorry if I didn't make that clearer in the original question

Comment: Ensure that you don't have any spaces in your python and path variables.

Comment: @rogerklutz: Just make sure you're adding ";C:\python27" to the PATH variable that already exists, and not creating a new variable with "C:\python27" as the value.

Comment: In many cases, you also have to log out and back in after setting the Path variable.

Comment: Suffering a similar problem, had done everything but step 5... Thank you for including that.

Comment: The main problem with this answer is that not all computers (ex. laptops) have a <kbd>PAUSE</kbd>. I think that using kenichi's answer is cross release, and cross hardware.

Comment: Small precision (which is what got me): once the path variable has been modified, **click on OK** (do not close by clicking on the X), then click again on OK on the variables window. If you don't, the changes will not be saved (not so obvious when you're used to Linux).

Comment: What is the difference for setting environment variable for User and System?

Answer (score 114):

When setting Environmental Variables in Windows, I have gone wrong on many, many occasions.
I thought I should share a few of my past mistakes here hoping that it might help someone.
(These apply to all Environmental Variables, not just when setting Python Path)

Watch out for these possible mistakes:

1. Kill and reopen your shell window: Once you make a change to the ENVIRONMENTAL Variables, you have to **restart** the window you are testing it on.
2. **NO SPACES** when setting the Variables. Make sure that you are adding the `;C:\Python27` WITHOUT any spaces. (It is common to try `C:\SomeOther; C:\Python27` That space (␣) after the semicolon is *not okay.)*
3. USE A **BACKWARD SLASH** when spelling out your full path. You will see forward slashes when you try `echo $PATH` but only backward slashes have worked for me.
4. **DO NOT ADD a final backslash**. Only `C:\Python27` NOT `C:\Python27\`

Comment: The reason that I chose this answer is that most of the time the PATH get's broken because of one of these 4 things. The easy part is doing it correctly, the hard part is noticing when you did it incorrectly!

Comment: The command `echo $path` is only valid if you're running a bash shell under windows (e.g. MinGW).  The windows command prompt command is `echo %path%`

Comment: I haven't found the trailing backlash to be problematic. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 53):

Open **cmd**.exe with administrator privileges (right click on app). Then type:

> **setx** path "%path%;C:\Python27;"

Remember to end with a semi-colon and don't include a trailing slash.

Comment: +1- This lets you add to the path without needing admin privileges.  However, I am not sure the %path% is needed.  On my Windows 7 system, new cmd windows now have two copies of the previous paths.

Comment: %path% is your old path variable value, it is there so "C:\Python27;" will be appended to your existing path.

Answer (score 32):

I've had a problem with this for a LONG time. I added it to my path in every way I could think of but here's what finally worked for me:

1. Right click on "My computer"
2. Click "Properties"
3. Click "Advanced system settings" in the side panel
4. Click "Environment Variables"
5. **Click the "New" below system variables**
6. **in name enter `pythonexe`** (or anything you want)
7. **in value enter the path to your python** (example: `C:\Python32\`)
8. **Now edit the Path variable (in the system part) and add `%pythonexe%;` to the end of what's already there**

IDK why this works but it did for me.

then try typing "python" into your command line and it should work!

---

Edit:

Lately I've been using [this program](http://eveditor.com/) which seems to work pretty well. There's also [this one](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) which looks pretty good too, although I've never tried it.

Answer (score 17):

Try adding this `python.bat` file to `System32` folder and the command line will now run python when you type in `python`

**python.bat**

```
@C:\Python27\python.exe %*
```

Source:

https://github.com/KartikTalwar/dotfiles/blob/master/bat/python.bat

Answer (score 14):

You can set the path from the **current cmd window** using the `PATH =` command. That will only add it for the current cmd instance. if you want to add it permanently, you should add it to system variables. (Computer > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables)

You would goto your cmd instance, and put in `PATH=C:/Python27/;%PATH%`.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Win7 Pro . Tested with `echo %PATH~%`.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you don't add a space before the new directory.

Good:
old;old;old;new

Bad:
old;old;old; new

Answer (score 8):

The following program will add the python executable path and the subdir Scripts (which is where e.g. pip and easy_install are installed) to your environment. It finds the path to the python executable from the registry key binding the .py extension. It will remove old python paths in your environment. Works with XP (and probably Vista) as well.
It only uses modules that come with the basic windows installer.

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys
import os
import time
import _winreg
import ctypes

def find_python():
    """
    retrieves the commandline for .py extensions from the registry
    """
    hKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                           r'Python.File\shell\open\command')
    # get the default value
    value, typ = _winreg.QueryValueEx (hKey, None)
    program = value.split('"')[1]
    if not program.lower().endswith(r'\python.exe'):
        return None
    return os.path.dirname(program)

def extend_path(pypath, remove=False, verbose=0, remove_old=True,
                script=False):
    """
    extend(pypath) adds pypath to the PATH env. variable as defined in the
    registry, and then notifies applications (e.g. the desktop) of this change.
    !!! Already opened DOS-Command prompts are not updated. !!!
    Newly opened prompts will have the new path (inherited from the 
    updated windows explorer desktop)
    options:
    remove (default unset), remove from PATH instead of extend PATH
    remove_old (default set), removes any (old) python paths first
    script (default unset), try to add/remove the Scripts subdirectory 
        of pypath (pip, easy_install) as well
    """
    _sd = 'Scripts' # scripts subdir
    hKey = _winreg.OpenKey (_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
               r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment',
               0, _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)

    value, typ = _winreg.QueryValueEx (hKey, "PATH")
    vals = value.split(';')
    assert isinstance(vals, list)
    if not remove and remove_old:
        new_vals = []
        for v in vals:
            pyexe = os.path.join(v, 'python.exe')
            if v != pypath and os.path.exists(pyexe):
                if verbose > 0:
                    print 'removing from PATH:', v
                continue
            if script and v != os.path.join(pypath, _sd) and \
               os.path.exists(v.replace(_sd, pyexe)):
                if verbose > 0:
                    print 'removing from PATH:', v
                continue
            new_vals.append(v)
        vals = new_vals
    if remove:
        try:
            vals.remove(pypath)
        except ValueError:
            if verbose > 0:
                print 'path element', pypath, 'not found'
            return
        if script:
            try:
                vals.remove(os.path.join(pypath, _sd))
            except ValueError:
                pass
            print 'removing from PATH:', pypath
    else:
        if pypath in vals:
            if verbose > 0:
                print 'path element', pypath, 'already in PATH'
            return
        vals.append(pypath)
        if verbose > 1:
            print 'adding to PATH:', pypath
        if script:
            if not pypath + '\\Scripts' in vals:
                vals.append(pypath + '\\Scripts')
            if verbose > 1:
                print 'adding to PATH:', pypath + '\\Scripts'
    _winreg.SetValueEx(hKey, "PATH", 0, typ, ';'.join(vals) )
    _winreg.SetValueEx(hKey, "OLDPATH", 0, typ, value )
    _winreg.FlushKey(hKey)
    # notify other programs
    SendMessage = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW
    HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1A
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, u'Environment')
    if verbose > 1:
        print 'Do not forget to restart any command prompts'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove = '--remove' in sys.argv
    script = '--noscripts' not in sys.argv
    extend_path(find_python(), verbose=2, remove=remove, script=script)
```

Comment: This ruined my PATH. Here is a fixed version (I also removed remove_old, which is impossible* to get right): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fb5d176ab91dccbd0ebd

* yes

Answer (score 8):

Python comes with a [small utility that does just this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Tools/scripts/win_add2path.py).  From the command line run:

```
c:\python27\tools\scripts\win_add2path.py
```

Make sure you close the command window (with `exit` or the close button) and open it again.

Comment: As for me, it does changes the register but none app will be affected until you manually confirm the changes via std GUI dialog. Restarting an app does not help. It looks like a kind of broadcasting is needed also.

Comment: This worked for me on 8.1 and seems easier than other approaches. A window/box opens up and asks what you want to run. Select Other and then navigate back to c:\python27 and pick the python executable (.exe). The effect appears to be permanent so you need do that only once. You will need to run win_add2path.py for every user but you don't get the box after the first time.

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is old but I'd like to add that the solutions assume admin privs. If you don't have those you can:

Go to control panel, type path (this is Windows 7 now so that's in the Search box) and click "Edit Environment variables for your account". You'll now see the Environment Variable dialog with "User variables" on the top and "System variables" below.

You can, as a user, click the top "New" button and add:

Variable name: **PATH**
Variable value: **C:\Python27**

(no spaces anywhere) and click OK. Once your command prompt is restarted, any PATH in the User variables is *appended* to the end of the System Path. It doesn't replace the PATH in any other way.

If you want a specific full path set up, you're better off creating a batch file like this little one:

```
@echo off
PATH C:\User\Me\Programs\mingw\bin;C:\User\Me\Programs;C:\Windows\system32
title Compiler Environment - %Username%@%Computername%
cmd
```

Call it "compiler.bat" or whatever and double click to start it. Or link to it. Or pin it etc...

Answer (score 6):

You need to make changes in your system variable
-- Right click on "My computer"
-- Click "Properties"
-- Click "Advanced system settings" in the side panel
-- Click on Environment Variable -- You will two sections of user variable and system variable
-- Under system variable section search for the variable 'Path' click on edit and add
  `"C:\Python27;"` (without quotes) save it
-- Now open command line type 'path' hit enter you will see path variable has been modified
-- Now type `python --version` you will see the python version

And it is done

Answer (score 5):

For anyone trying to achieve this with Python 3.3+, the Windows installer now includes an option to add python.exe to the system search path. Read more in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable).

Comment: This is what I used, because I was having trouble finding the exact path of the install. Start up the installer, hit 'Modify' and then on the Optional Features, click next, then check the box to add Python to the system path and hit Finish.

Answer (score 4):

Working with Windows environment variables is always a horrible experience. Recently, I found an amazing tool called Rapid Environment Editor, which gives an awesomely simple GUI for managing them.

If you use chocolatey, you can install it using `choco install rapidee`. Otherwise, take a look at http://www.rapidee.com/en/download
[image]

Re-reading this, it sounds like a paid shill, but I swear I'm not! It's just been one of the most useful utilities in my toolkit for a while and I'm surprised no one seems to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

If Python was installed with another program, such as ArcGIS 10.1 in my case, then you also must include any extra folders that path to the python.exe in your Environment Variables.

So my Environment Variables looks like this:

System variables > Path > add `;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1`

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old, but I just ran into a similar problem and my particular solution wasn't listed here:

**Make sure you don't have a folder in your PATH that doesn't exist.**

In my case, I had a bunch of default folders (Windows, Powershell, Sql Server, etc) and then a custom `C:\bin` that I typically use, and then various other tweaks like `c:\python17`, etc. It turns out that the cmd processor was finding that `c:\bin` didn't exist and then stopped processing the rest of the variable.

Also, I don't know that I ever would have noticed this without [PATH manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pathmanager/). It nicely highlighted the fact that that item was invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed Python 3.3 on Windows 7 using the option "add python to PATH".

In PATH variable, the installer automatically added a **final backslash**: `C:\Python33\`
and so **it did not work** on command prompt (i tried closing/opening the prompt several times)

**I removed the final backslash** and then it worked: `C:\Python33`

Thanks Ram Narasimhan for your tip #4 !

Answer (score 2):

I organized my python environment variable like this under Win7 64-bit using cmd.

I set the variable `PYTHONPATH` via environment variable menue of windows and added `%PYTHONPATH%` to the `PATH` variable:

`...;%PYTHONPATH%`

The cmd shell expands the variable correctly to this:

```
C:\>echo %PYTHONPATH%
C:\python27;c:\python27\lib;C:\python27\scripts
```

Do not forget to restart cmd shell after changing PATH.

Answer (score 1):

For people getting the windows store window when writing python in the console, all you have to do is go to `configuration -> Manage app execution aliases` and disable the toggles that say python.

then, add the following folders to the PATH.

```
C:\Users\alber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
```

```
C:\Users\alber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\
```

Answer (score 0):

write that on your Command Prompt:

```
set Path=%path%
```

Replace %path% by the Path of your Python Folder Example:

```
set Path=C:/Python27
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, run this:

```
C:\Users\username> cd C:\bin
C:\bin> echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd
```

Make sure, you have installed phpuunit as stated here: https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/installation.html

Then:

```
phpunit path-to-your-test
```

Answer (score 0):

For an `anaconda3` installation the paths to add are:

```
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Scripts\
%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Library\bin\
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have got frustrated by setting the path for the python just download the new version of python uninstall the older version of the python and while installing the new version it will ask whether to set path mark that and install

its the best way