# problem in python relative import

Tags: python, package

I am running the following project on windows with the following directory structure..

```
Project\Src\Lib\General\Module_lib.py  
Project\Src\executables\example.py
```

Now , I want to import `Module_lib.py` in `example.py`.. Please help me how to solve this?

content of `example.py` :

```
from ..lib.general.Module_lib import Module_lib
```

output :

```
Value Error : Attempted relative import in non-packages
```

what is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Add `Project\Src\Lib\General` to your PYTHON_PATH so the runtime can find it. That's the only real convenient solution I can think of.

You can find a way of adding your python path here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Doing it in script is also possible:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

This won't work out of the box because the `dirname` call is to your current file. To fix this you can call it multiple times to move up directories. I hope this is clear enough.

```
dir1 = os.path.dirname(__file__)
dir1up = os.path.dirname(dir1)
dir1upup = os.path.dirname(dir1up)
```

Comment: Well, it's system dependent. What OS are you running?

Comment: but I need to do it in my script .. so that there will be no dependency when I run these scripts on multiple PC

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the PYTHONPATH environment variable so that it contains all the directories where you want Python to look for your modules. Assuming that your source tree is in the root of the C: drive you have two options:

1. Add all the leaf directories to PYTHONPATH and import your modules directly e.g.:

   ```
   set PYTHONPATH=C:\Project\Src\Lib\General
   ```

   In this case you can import your module directly:

   ```
   import Module_lib
   ```
2. Make packages of your directories by adding empty files named `__init__.py`, so that you may use qualified names to import your modules and have less directories to add to your PYTHONPATH. You could do something like:

   ```
   set PYTHONPATH=C:\Project\Src
   ```

   In this case you can import your module with a suitable qualified name:

   ```
   import Lib.General.Module_lib
   ```

   To achieve this you need to add an empty file named `__init__.py` to the C:\Project\Src\Lib and the C:\Project\Src\Lib\General directories.