# Running setup.py install for pycrypto 'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, django, windows, dependencies, pycrypto

There is python 2.7 and already pycrypto 2.6.1 inside installed. 
Env Windows 8, x64.

I get following error while installing requirements with pip (pip install -r file_with_requirements).

```
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Found existing installation: pycrypto 2.6
    Uninstalling pycrypto:
      Successfully uninstalled pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto
    'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I've tried with normal user and admin privileages as well.

Comment: maybe [this SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405549/how-do-i-install-pycrypto-on-windows) would help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install msys package under MinGW

[image]

and add following entries in your PATH env variable.

- `C:\MinGW\bin`
- `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` [This is where you will find chmod executable]

Then run your command from normal windows command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Install cygwin and setp can download from following link
http://cygwin.com/