# How to fix "ImportError: cannot import name _AES" from Crypto.Cipher

Tags: python, importerror, pycrypto

I'm using the `pycrypto` module to encrypt files. When running the python code, it works well:

```
$ python encrypt_file.py file
```

but when I build `encrypt_file.py` to a binary:

```
$ pyinstaller -F zip_disk.py
```

and run the binary under `dist`

```
$ ./encrypt_file file
```

it shows the following error:

```
File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "/home/xxxx/zip_disk/build/zip_disk/out00-PYZ.pyz/Crypto.Cipher.AES", line 50, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name _AES
```

Why does this happen?
How to fix `ImportError`?

- My import statement is

  ```
  from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  ```
- Python version: Python 2.7.6
- PyCrypto version is [2.6.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto). I have tried to install `pycrypto` from source and via `pip`, both result in the the same `ImportError`.
- Platform: Linux Ubuntu 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Most likely extensions are not built (or if built) are not in correct path for you.

Comment: @gabhijit:  I have tried install `pycrypto` from source and via `pip`, both the same `ImportError`

Comment: Maybe you could refer to [Python AES import error Please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943136/python-aes-import-error-please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pycrypto developers have stopped futher upgrades. Use instead pycryptodome which replaces pycrypto.

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

Now it works fine (did for me)!