# How can pyOIDC be installed on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, openid-connect

The [quick install guide](http://pyoidc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) for pyOIDC says to run `python setup.py install` (after installing the prerequisites).

When I try this I get :

> RuntimeError: chmod error
>   'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Obviously, it looks like it's expecting Linux, but I'm running Windows.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405549/how-do-i-install-pycrypto-on-windows) (which I needed for one of the prerequisites) has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11405769/2434902) saying:

> If you don't already have a C/C++ development environment installed that is compatible with the Visual Studio binaries distributed by Python.org, then you should stick to installing only pure Python packages or packages for which a Windows binary is available.

Well, I don't have a C/C++ development environment installed that is compatible with the Visual Studio binaries distributed by Python.org (at least, I assume I don't, and that I'd know if I did!).

So is there a pure Python package for pyOIDC, or is there a Windows installer, or is pyOIDC just not compatible with Windows?!

Comment: It looks like this is actually a PyCrypto problem. We can download PyCrypto 2.6 from here: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto, but pyOIDC requires 2.6.1, and this is what triggers the chmod error.