# Installing pyCrypto on Windows 7 fails

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pyCrypto 2.6.1 on Windows 7 x64 running Python 3.4.2, but upon running `<path to pip> install pycrypto`, I get `Command ""C:\Program Files\Python 3.4.2\python.exe" ... " failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ih8shygg\pycrypto` (the ellipsis is mine). The command it was running when it failed had `exec(compile(getattr(` in it. I also tried the pre-built binaries, but the installer freezes up on me. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please read the existing questions on this topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install PyCrypto on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405549/how-do-i-install-pycrypto-on-windows)