# ImportError: No module named Crypto

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto

I am just starting to explore Python. I am trying to run an AES algorithm code and I am facing the:

> ImportError: No module named Crypto.

How do you solve this?

Comment: Install it: `pip install pycrypto`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install PyCrypto on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405549/how-do-i-install-pycrypto-on-windows)

Comment: the trouble is, there is another package called Crypto and a lot of folks install that first. and it doesn't work. `pycrypto` is the right package.. I wonder if the command ought to be changed for disambiguation? `from pycryto.Cipher..` never seen this divergence from naming convention with other packages.

Answer (score 12):

You have to install crypto package. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto

Comment: I've installed it. Used : pip install pycrypto.

Comment: I guess you've tried to import "import crypto" But in docs,it shows like that "from Crypto.Cipher import AES"

Comment: Solved it . Had to change the name from crypto to Crypto. Thank you !

Comment: There is another Crypto package that we end up installing instead of pycrypto. There should be a way to disambiguate.. module name to use in code ought to mirror the official name of the module.

Comment: I get an error saying `ImportError: cannot import name Padding` whenever I type `from Crypto.Util import Padding`. I observed that the Padding file is not present in Util. How do I find a pycrypto package with Padding in Util

Answer (score 7):

`pip install pycryptodome`

It can fix the follows:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Padding' from 'Crypto.Util'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**:

By installing **pycrypto** module from your **virtualenv**

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved when i installed pycrypto rather then crypto
`pip2 install pycrypto`