# from Crypto.Cipher import AES / ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

Tags: python-3.x, pycrypto

I am not able to run my code, this error appears. I've tried in several ways to install pycrypto.
pip install pycrypto -> PyCrypto -> Crypto -> crypto -> pycryptodome .... and so on. Some help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named Crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738083/importerror-no-module-named-crypto)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have installed modules that interfere with eachother.
Uninstall all modules that you listed above, including pycryptdome.
Only then reinstall pycryptdome.

See detailed answer to [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62401839/317460)