# PyCrypto on python 3.5

Tags: python, pycrypto

I found some PyCrypto installers for Python 3.3 and 3.4, but nothing for Python 3.5.

When I try to install PyCrypton using `pip install`, it says:

```
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
```

Is there any way to install PyCrypto on Python 3.5 in Windows 10? Thanks!

Comment: BEST Solution Here: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html

Comment: @JeremiahBarrar Just commenting to increase visibility - PyCrypto is dead, use Pycryptodome now as linked above.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That warning shouldn't stop the build, more likely you are lacking the Visual Studio 2015 compiler which is necessary to build binary extensions (which PyCrypto has). See the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/extensions/#building-binary-extensions) for which compiler you need for your version of Python.

The reason you need the compiler is PyCrypto only offers a Source Distribution officially. So, you have two options for installing PyCrypto:

## 1. Build from source:

This is actually fairly simple, but it requires that you install some extra software. Again, refer to the Python Packaging User Guide linked above to find the suitable compiler for your version of Python. I think that there is an option to only install the relevant compiler for Python if you do a custom install of Visual Studio.

Then, after the installation is completed, and you probably had to restart your computer, you should be able to simply run `pip install pycrypto` and pip will download the source and compile it for you.

If you also installed wheel (`pip install wheel`) then pip will create a wheel from the source and cache it, which is how I created the wheels that I'm sharing in option 2.

## 2. Install a Built Distribution from a 3rd party

I happen to be a 3rd party and have shared wheels I compiled for PyCrypto 2.6.1 w/ Python 3.5 for 32 and 64-bit Windows [on my GitHub repo](https://github.com/sfbahr/PyCrypto-Wheels). I included installation instructions on the readme of that repo.

If you're looking for a built distribution for an older version of Python and/or PyCrypto, I've also linked to Voidspace on my repo's readme (sorry, I'm limited to 2 links here).

Comment: That is a great help!

Comment: Excelent work @sfbahr, saved me from a world of pain.

Comment: Now I am looking for python3.6 64bit windows :|

Answer (score 23):

Use **pycryptodome** instead! It is a project still maintained (june 2017) and includes the functions of pycrypto for python 3.xx (It worked for me on python 3.6)

Project Page:

https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I use pycrypto on Linux, and this worked great for testing the server in a windows environment. Has the exact same interface as pycrypto, it's a drop-in replacement.

Comment: `pip3 install pycryptodome` with repo [here](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome).

Comment: I tried it, but the application I was trying to run, returned ATTRIBUTE ERROR: https://github.com/mach1el/pchat

Answer (score 5):

You can try [PyCryptodome](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.org), a fork of PyCrypto. It has Windows wheels for Python 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple solution for Python 3.x version:**

```
easy_install http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/pycrypto-2.6.1/pycrypto-2.6.1.win-amd64-py3.4.exe
```