# Python 3.5 SFTP file transfer

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pycrypto

I would like to use paramiko for SFTP file transfer in Python 3.5. I know that paramiko depends on PyCrypto and have read about PyCrypto installation problems in Python 3.5. Although I have seen a number of questions regarding this topic, I have not found a solution to successful SFTP file transfer in Python 3.5.

**My first question**: is it possible to use Python 3.5 for SFTP file transfer? If so, will paramiko work? If the above will work, why I am I receiving the following errors when attempting to install PyCrypto?

```
error: [WinError 2] The system canot find the file specified
**Failed building wheel for pycrypto**
```

**My second question**: if paramiko will not work with Python 3.5, are there any alternatives or must I revert back to a previous python version for SFTP file transfer?

Comment: if you only need to transfer from A to B, `rsync`?

Comment: rsync will not work, this must be done through sftp

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800336/pycrypto-on-python-3-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install Python 3.5.1 on my Linux server and then `pip install paramiko` from there. I'm still not sure why PyCrypto cannot be installed in Python 3.5 for Windows but this was the only solution I was able to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can install PyCrypto binaries for Python 3.5 if you don't have a C++ compiler installed (that pip need to use to compile this library)

Install a PyCrypto binary from this site :
https://github.com/sfbahr/PyCrypto-Wheels

The best way to do it, is:

**64bits Python**

c:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=https://github.com/sfbahr/PyCrypto-Wheels/raw/master/pycrypto-2.6.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl pycrypto

**32bits Python**

c:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=https://github.com/sfbahr/PyCrypto-Wheels/raw/master/pycrypto-2.6.1-cp35-none-win32.whl pycrypto

Of course replace *c:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe* by your python pip path

To know your python version, run python and look at the architecture displayed between brackets:

C:\Users\utilisateur>python

Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 **64 bit** (**AMD64**)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Hope this can help.