# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having problem with tensorflow. I want to use ImageDataGenerator, but I'm receiving error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'. Not sure what is the problem. I added this tf.**version** to test will it work, and it shows the version of tensorflow.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    print(tf.__version__)
    from tf.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

When I run this code, I get this:

```
2.1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q:/TF/Kamen papir maaze/rks.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tf.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'
```

Comment: just change it to tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image

Comment: Yes, the module is called tensorflow, not tf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get around the " No module named 'Crypto' " error after doing "pip install pycrypto"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994590/how-do-i-get-around-the-no-module-named-crypto-error-after-doing-pip-inst)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The line

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

means you are importing tensorflow with an alias as tf to call it modules/functions.

You cannot use the alias to import other modules.

For your case, if you call directly

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(...)
```

then it will work.

or

you need to import the module with the right module name. i.e.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, tested on kaggle with `tf_v2.6` and `tf_v2.7`

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
...
```

Answer (score -2):

in Tensorflow 2.0+, to use `keras` instead of `tf` use `tensorflow` always-

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Comment: the code you provided produces the same error the OP is confused about.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question