# "Stopped working" error when installing PyCrypto

Tags: installation, pycrypto

I am attempting to install PyCrypto under Windows 7, 64 bit.

I downloaded and installed [ActiveState's Python 2.7.10.12, 64 bit,](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) without issue. The interactive shell appears to work fine.

Next, I went to [VoidSpace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto) and downloaded PyCrypto 2.6 for Python 2.7 64bit (`pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`). I ran it and accepted the default folders and clicked “Next” twice, after which it crashed with the following message from Windows:

```
pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe has stopped working
```

and no other information.

I downloaded the file again and rebooted the computer and got the same result several times.

How can I figure out why it won’t install and what to do about it?

Comment: Attempted fix: Went offline and turned off antivirus scanning and firewall (BitDefender), then tried again to install PyCrypto. Same result as before, so that was not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I did some more digging and found the problem, which is:

```
The installation file has to be "Run as administrator."
```

In other words, right click the file name and select "Run as administrator."

It's as simple as that.

Here's what I did to figure that out:

Looking at the StackOverflow post, *[How do I install PyCrypto on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405549/how-do-i-install-pycrypto-on-windows)*, I noticed some suggestions to run the installation file using `easy_install`, so I tried that. (`easy_install` is in the `Python27\Scripts` folder.) That gave me a long error message, which said something about signing in as an administrator. I am the administrator, but this gave me the idea that maybe the file wants to run as an administrator. So I tried that and Voila! The installation proceeded to completion.

I don’t know if there’s a reason that I had to do that and other people don’t have to. I've sent an e-mail to Michael at VoidSpace suggesting that he add a note near the download links suggesting that it be run that way.