# Python file structure about importing from other directories

Tags: python, import

I have problems with importing some functions in the file stored in other directories and importing random method from Crypto library.

I installed Python34 and PyCrypto 2.6.1 in window 7.

Here is my file structure

my_project
   
       /dh
      
           /__pycache__
      
           /__init__.py
   
       ./lib
      
           /__init__.py
      
           /helpers.py

In the /dh/__init__.py file
I have three import statements as follows

from Crypto.Hash import SHA256 -> it is fine



from Crypto.Random import random -> gives me error "from Crypto.Random import OSRNG ImportError: cannot import name 'OSRNG' "



from lib.helpers import read_hex --> gives me error "from lib.helpers import read_hex ImportError: No module named 'lib' "

I found out that there is not such file or folder OSRNG in Python34/Lib/sit-packages/Crypto/Random/

How can I fix these two errors?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer as I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I tried this in my system, I am able to import all the modules/Classes mentioned in the question. I do see the OSRNG directory.

Are you sure you installed it properly? Try reinstalling it. 
Also, are you using a virtualenv? If so, may be you forgot to activate it?

Comment: Should I use virtualenv? To be honest I don't know about it can you tell a bit more about it?

Comment: You don't have to unless you are working on multiple projects each requiring a separate python environment.
You can check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial if you are interested to learn.
Since you are not aware of virtualenv, I assume you have not used it.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266
Install that first and then reinstall pycrypto.
This should resolve your problem.

Comment: oh I installed the file from your link and reinstalled the pycrypto but it still gives me errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405549/how-do-i-install-pycrypto-on-windows
I hope that one helps :)