# Installing python simple-crypt on Windows10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to install the simple-crypt module for python 3.7 on the Windows 10 command line  and don't really understand what is problem here. Can anyone help me?

```
pip install simple-crypt
Collecting simple-crypt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/66/5bf6feb073f715a61492f8a6d444ad3d884ada71af317ce7a9c80bebee60/simple-crypt-4.1.7.tar.gz
Collecting pycrypto (from simple-crypt)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/db/645aa9af249f059cc3a368b118de33889219e0362141e75d4eaf6f80f163/pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, simple-crypt
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3yxh_4i2\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-67180j7m\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -Ic:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/winrand.obj
    winrand.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(29): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(43): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(49): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(57): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(64): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(70): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(77): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(83): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(90): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(96): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3yxh_4i2\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-67180j7m\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3yxh_4i2\pycrypto\
```

I tried installing it in a virtual linux machine and it worked fine, but on Windows it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

I have Windows 7 and Python 3.8 but this is how I did it.

Install pycryptodome instead of pycrypto. Pycryptodome is a fork of pycrypto and you should not use pycrypto anymore.

```
pip3 install pycryptodome
```

Install simple-crypt without dependencies

```
pip3 install simple-crypt --no-dependencies
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @tok for your feedback..I had been looking for this and your solution has worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `simple-crypt` but its main dependency `pycrypto`.

The problem is that `pycrypto` requires the compilation of C code and this is bound to fail by just naively using `pip install ...`.

However, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405549/how-do-i-install-pycrypto-on-windows) to get to know workarounds for installing it on Windows.

Once `pycrypto` is available to your interpreter (i.e. `import Crypto` works), then you may want install the other `simple-crypt` dependencies manually (through `pip`) and finally install `simple-crypt` from `pip` with the `--no-dependencies` flag.

Comment: i have pycrypt installed , i tried uninstalling it and then running pip install simple-crypt still same result. But i will try this your link.                                                                                 
 C:\Users\PC>pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------
asn1crypto   0.24.0
cffi         1.12.3
cryptography 2.7
funcy        1.12
future       0.17.1
pip          19.1.1
pycparser    2.19
pycrypt      0.7.2
pycryptodome 3.8.2
pyserial     3.4
setuptools   41.0.1
six          1.12.0

Comment: Have you ensured that the `pycrypto` installation can be found by `pip`?

Comment: how do i do that ? i can import pycrypto modules , it works fine, no errors at all Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
>>> from Crypto import Random
>>>

Comment: OK, than you may want install the other `simple-crypt` dependencies manually (through `pip`) and finally install `simple-crypt` from `pip` with the `--no-dependencies` flag. It should work.