# Running continuous PHP (script) background processes on a WAMP server

Tags: php, twitter, process, background, wamp

I got the 140dev Twitter framework (which uses the Twitter phirehose) manually 
running (via the webbrowser on my local wamp server), but I can't 
figure out how to run both get_tweets.php and parse_tweets.php as a 
background process like with SSH commands:

```
nohup php script.php > /dev/null &
```

Some of you started using (the Windows equivalent of) cronjobs, but 
this isn't the right way to go. I think this is because of creating 
multiple connection (or re-connections) to the Twitter streaming phirehose isn't allowed? 
How can I run both PHP scripts (get_tweets.php and parse_tweets.php) 
as a background process on my local WAMP server (and later on a VPS)?

Just to clearify:

- I am using a WAMP server (first to test a little bit and later to 
  run it on a VPS)
- **Using LAMP or any *nix server/system isn't an option** (due to time, 
  experience and lack of skills)
- I have searched for solutions (on google and stackoverflow), but they are either not working or not clear enough for me (I am new to this)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about running a PHP based windows service (net start/net stop etc...). From php.net doc: "The win32service extension is a Windows specific extension that allows PHP to communicate with the Service Control Manager to start, stop, register and unregister services, and even allows your PHP scripts to run as a service." http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.win32service.php

Comment: @UgoMéda Méda: I used the following solutions:
$com = new Com('WScript.shell');
$com->run('php yourscript.php', 0, false);

as a .bat file and a .php file in combination with Freebyte task scheduler but this didn't work. I added the php path to environment variables to use ('php...). I also used other .bat files with the following code:
'@ECHO OFF
php -f script.php' or something like this. But this also didn't work.
CyrilTourist: looks interesting I will have a look at it.

Note: I am quite new to all this php and server stuff so that makes it hard.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `php/bin` folder where the `php.exe` is located. Copy the folder path and add it to your PATH environment variable (Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7) for instance to edit your PATH variable.

Once this is done, you'll be able to execute php in the command line from anywhere. Just start `php script.php` with a command line in the right folder and it should work. There might be some configuration to make so that the php in command line uses WAMP's php.ini.

Comment: "execute php in the command line from anywhere" This is probably my problem. I don't quite understand this part. Should I open cmd and navigate to the script.php folder to start it?  Or do I have an alternative route/approach?    And what about that last part "configuring php in command line to use WAMP's php.ini"?

Comment: Yes, open cmd in your script forlder and start it. You can create a bat to do it.

Comment: I opened cmd and "cd-ed" to the right folder. I then used php-win -f script.php to start the process and it worked! using the php -f script.php command didn't let me close the cmd box and php-win runs in the background. Final question is whether this also works on a VPS? Can I use remote desktop connection to start cmd and do exactly the same as with my wamp server?