# Python not calling external program

Tags: python, postgresql

I am having problems with a python program that I wrote.  It is actually plpython3u.  I am running the program as a Trigger from postgres.  I am pretty sure the trigger part works.  My test python program only does 2 things right now.  It writes some junk to a file and then it tries to run a program that is on my C: drive (this is a Windows system, BTW).  I am able to write to the file so the python program is being called correctly.  As a test the program that I am trying to run is a BAT file that just does a COPY. The copy is never done so my code calling the external program is not working.   Ultimately I want this to call a true Windows app (with a window to come up.  Is this the best way to do this?    Also,  I got all the python stuff set up via a  question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106388/postgres-and-python)

I am using a Winows 7 machine with python32.  Although it probably does not matter, I am using postgres 9.2 and I am running everything all of this via a SQL window from pgAdmin 1.16

Here is the code with the problem:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION scalesmyone (thename text)
  RETURNS int
AS $$
a=5
f = open('C:\\JUNK\\frompython.txt','w')
f.write(thename)
f.close()
import os
os.system('"C:\\Users\\Jim\\Desktop\\BATfiles\\run_addcust.bat"')
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: @Jun, Sorry for the delay: I get the error that I got previously when I was setting up the system.  Partof it is here and I will post the rest in a different comment and the code also: ERROR:  WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 7, in <module>
    return_code = subprocess.call(['"C:\\Users\\Jim\\Desktop\\BATfiles\\run_addcust.bat"', "hello"])
  PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 470, in call
  PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 744, in __init__

Comment: @jun Part 2 of the error:   PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 963, in _execute_child
PL/Python function "scalesmyone"
SQL statement "SELECT scalesmyone(new.id)"
PL/pgSQL function scalesins_function() line 13 at PERFORM

********** Error **********

ERROR: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
SQL state: XX000  Context: Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 7, in <module>
    return_code = subprocess.call(['"C:\\Users\\Jim\\Desktop\\BATfiles\\run_addcust.bat"', "hello"])

Comment: Part 3 of the error:  PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 470, in call
  PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 744, in __init__
  PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 963, in _execute_child
PL/Python function "scalesmyone"
SQL statement "SELECT scalesmyone(new.id)"
PL/pgSQL function scalesins_function() line 13 at PERFORM

Comment: @jun,  The code: I tried different combinations of the single and double quotes:  CREATE or replace FUNCTION scalesmyone (thename text)
  RETURNS int
AS $$
a=5
f = open('C:\\JUNK\\frompython.txt','w')
f.write(thename)
f.close()
import subprocess
return_code = subprocess.call(['"C:\\Users\\Jim\\Desktop\\BATfiles\\run_addcust.bat"', "hello"])
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;

Comment: @jun when I tried it this way I get an error saying it cannot find the file.  I copied and pasted the BAT line into a Command Window and replaced the double backslashes with singles and it found the file... The code: return_code = subprocess.call(["'C:\\Users\\Jim\\Desktop\\BATfiles\\run_addcust.bat'", '"hello"'])     Error: ERROR:  WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to the the subprocess but I still have a problem with the Windows 7  Folders having read-only permissions.  I asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364928/python-not-calling-an-external-program-part-2%22here%22)