# Python not calling an external program part 2

Tags: python, postgresql

I am having problems running a python program (plpython3u, really) as a trigger from postgres (9.2).   The trigger calls the python program with the following statement:
perform  scalesmyone(new.id);

The python program writes something to a file successfully (which indicates to me that the trigger is working) and then tries to run a program on the C: drive on my Windows 7 machine. It fails on that  with this error:  ERROR:  WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied.    I am using a subprocess call now  but previously I tried a subprocess call but that did not work.  You can see that  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278109/python-not-calling-external-program)

Here is the code:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION scalesmyone (thename text)
RETURNS int
AS $$
a=5
f = open('C:\\JUNK\\frompython.txt','w')
f.write(thename)
f.close()
import subprocess
return_code = subprocess.call(["C:\\Users\\Jim\\Desktop\\BATfiles\\run_addcust.bat", '"hello"'])
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

The file is there.

Jim

Comment: Do you have a traceback? If you do, please post it. Is the error on the `f =` line, or on the `return_code =` one?

Comment: Does the trigger have execute permissions in the directory where the program is being triggered?  Or is it possible that triggers are firing close together so a second run is trying to write to the same file while the first run is still using the file?

Comment: @Thomas This is running the exe.It's the same error `code` CONTEXT: Traceback (most recent call last): PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 7, in <module> return_code = subprocess.call(['"C:\\Users\\Jim\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\addcustomer\\Debug\\AddNewCustomer.exe"', '"hello"']) PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 470, in call PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 744, in __init__ PL/Python function "scalesmyone", line 963, in _execute_child PL/Python function "scalesmyone" LAST TWO LINES IN NEXT COMMENT

Comment: @Jim edit your question with the stack trace

Comment: @Thomas The last two lines of the traceback from running the exe directly:   SQL statement "SELECT scalesmyone(new.id)"
PL/pgSQL function scalesins_function() line 13 at PERFORM

Comment: @falmari how?  Those shortcuts do not work

Comment: @Thomas, I think the traceback says that the problem is with the return_code line and noy thge f= line.

Comment: @theodox, How can I tell if the trigger has execute perms on the dir? There is just one user on the system (me) but I know that Windows 7 does odd things with sys Admin privs... How would the program be triggered twice? It is only called once. There can't be a second call, can there?  Also, the problem is not with the file it is with the subprocess call

Comment: The permissions for the bat file will be available as noted below - right click, properties, security - check the line for 'read and execute'.  It would be odd, however, for a file on your desktop that you created not to be executable for me.... BTW the 'U' in plpython3u is for 'untrusted,' since the server can't guarantee it won't be used maliciously -- is it possible your server is configured to prevent it from having access to your file system or executables?

Comment: @theodox, I will check the security. The BAT file is in a folder on my desktop. I did create both. The Read-only bit is turned on on the folder on my desktop. The EXE that I need to run is in the Documents area and that folder is Read-only also. I have been having a heck of a time getting that.It is not turnned on. I tried attrib but that did not work.I suspect that is the problem but I think your comment about the configuration is real.Is there anyway I can check the coniguration? Any ideas on how to get the Folder Read-Only to be changed? I will be looking to see if the Owner is correct next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests user that runs Postgres/plpython has no execution permissions on that .bat file (at least that's what I was getting in plain Python programs). This might not be a problem with subprocess itself.

Comment: How do I check the perms on the bat file?  Rt-click on the  file or are you thinking of something else?

Comment: A venture into unpleasant land awaits you, I mean new (2008/Win7) style permissions. 

Just kidding. Right click a file, click Properties, click Security tab. You have specific users (top pane) and permissions (bottom pane) there and you have to set the read and execute permissions correctly.

Comment: It's tricky sometimes though, it would be much simpler if you found who's the "owner" of the plpython process that's trying to create a file. Say, make this trigger/script write some file somewhere, like C:\temp or smth, and look up who's the owner of the created file (rclick, properties, security, advanced, click Owner tab). Then copy the .bat script into folder that is accessible for plpython process owner and give it that owner too. You can easily make those scripts editable by assigning yourself Full control privilege on that script. That way it will be accessible for both owners.

Comment: Yet another thing: what if your trigger/plpython process tries to write something into folder or file that it has no right to write to? that may be another problem. Stack trace would be extremely helpful if you can get it.

Comment: ,My original post may have been confusing, the COPY works. I did that just as a test to see if the trigger worked and it is. I am really trying to run the BAT or EXE files. That is my goal. If you can see the Stack trace it says that it has a permissions problem on the subprocess line. I looked last night. The file folders that have the BAT and EXE files have the READ-ONLY flag set in the perm window. Changing it didn't work. I used attrib -r <folder> to change it but that didn't work. I tried using flags but that did NOTHING. Any idea how I can change that? That is the real problem. @mrkafk

Comment: BTW,  the Stack trace is almost unreadable. Using mini-Markdown formattng does not work for me in these comments. Any idea how that is done?   `code` This should be formatted like code, correct?

Comment: @Jim: the problem is probably in OWNER. Are you sure you opened Security tab and Advanced tab? The owners and their rights are there. if you're on Windows 7 like you write you MUST get this right. R/O and traditional WinXP/2003 flags (IIRC) have no impact on this problem. Think of Win7 owners and permissions as mutation of UNIX-style owners and permissions. Read up on this. You have to have plpython OWNER have "Full control" / permissions high enough over what (files, folders) you're trying to read, execute or write. There's no other way around this.

Comment: @Jim: a better solution would be use pastie dot org or smth similar and paste link here.

Comment: I will try to change the owner of the dir. I have not done that yet.  I do not know who the plpython owner is, though.  I am running it so maybe I should be the owner?   Is that correct?

Comment: @Jim: I'm not familiar with Postgres on Windows, IIRC it runs as a service (correct me if I'm wrong), so the owner might be NETWORK_SERVICE or SYSTEM (that's how MS SQL Server is typically running, depending on installation settings). Postgres on Linux (worked with this) is highly modular, with separate processes running different services and using IPC (inter-process communication) facilities heavily. If it's on windows and has not been extensively modified for that purpose, I suspect it's similar. I'd recommend ProcessExplorer (free utility from MS) to look that up.

Comment: I was pulled away on a different project but I am working on this again. In the python code I created a folder by using the os.system command for a mkdir C:\temp. That made the folder successfully and I saw that the folder was owned by NETWORK SERVICE. I have been copying programs into this directory so they can be run by the python program. Actually, my program copies the programs into that dir so that the perms will be correct. However, I will need to run a program that cannot be copied. It is an installed program. Is there a better way to do this?