# QBXML Customer modify

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

In the QBSDK, I have an event setup using the sample EventSubscribe and EventHandler.  I am subscribing to a Customer Modify event. When I get the event, I get the xml code below.  It gives me the  ListID which allows me to get the current customer name.  However,  I need the old name also.  I am trying to update the name in Postgres and it needs the old name.   Is there some way I can get the old name?

Thanks,

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<?qbxml version="3.0" ?> 
<QBXML> 
    <QBXMLEvents> 
        <DataEvent> 
            <CompanyFilePath>C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Company Files\Shain Software.qbw</CompanyFilePath> 
            <HostInfo> 
                <ProductName>QuickBooks Pro 2012</ProductName> 
                <MajorVersion>22</MajorVersion> 
                <MinorVersion>0</MinorVersion> 
                <Country>US</Country> 
            </HostInfo> 
            <ListEvent> 
                <ListEventType>Customer</ListEventType> 
                <ListEventOperation>Modify</ListEventOperation> 
                <ListID>8000000A-1356377147</ListID> 
            </ListEvent> 
            <DataEventRecoveryTime>2013-03-01T15:16:35-05:00</DataEventRecoveryTime> 
        </DataEvent> 
    </QBXMLEvents> 
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get the old name.

You shouldn't need it.

Store the ListIDs in your database, and update based on that instead of the old name.

Comment: actually that was my SECOND best idea.... The problem is that I need to download all of the customer names and ListIDs when I start the program.... Is that what you are thinking of? Or were you thinking of something else?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I will be handling several different modifications.  I am not sure which yet but that means that I have to have extra copies of the data around.  For this I have to keep a ssid to name linkage.   It is not that big a deal....   Do you have any ideas about the other question I posted?  It is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721514/qbsdk-giving-error

Comment: For accurate synchronization, you'll need to store the ListID in your app and associate that with the object in your application, yes. You don't need to store any other data beyond that - as long as you store the ListID in your database and associate it with your record, then you already know the old name of it (it's whatever is in your app when you receive the event).