# Did I install pip correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and the tutorial I'm using suggested for me to install four important packages (distribute, pip, nose and virtual env).

I've installed the first two using setup.py in Windows PowerShell

Problem is I can't figure out how to use pip. I've tried doing commands for pip in the cmd, python idle shell and powershell. All of them return something similar to *pip is not defined or there is a syntax error*

Here's what i type which results to syntax error

```
pip freeze

pip list --outdated
```

Anyone know if I've done something wrong installing pip?

Notes:
I'm using Windows 7
I've checked the Python2.7 directory and pip is in the Scripts folder.
I've also used help("modules") in the Python Idle shell and it lists pip in the modules

Comment: Read this (it may help you): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: is `python/Scripts` in your path variable?\

Comment: Wow thanks that helped. I added C:\Python27\Scripts to the environment variables and now it works :D

Comment: yup thats how that stuff  works :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add an answer to this question (it was provided in the comments by Joran Beasley), the issue here was that `pip` installs to the `python/Scipts` directory, but that was not in the path by default on Windows. Adding `C:\Python27\Scripts` to the path fixed the issue. [This answer describes adding a directory to the path on Windows 7.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

if you've ubuntu you have just to install the pip with aptget

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```