# How do I run Python script using arguments in windows command line

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

This is my python `hello.py` script:

```
def hello(a,b):
    print "hello and that's your sum:"
    sum=a+b
    print sum
    import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello(sys.argv[2])
```

The problem is that it can't be run from the windows command line prompt, I used this command:

```
C:\Python27>hello 1 1
```

But it didn't work unfortunately, may somebody please help?

Comment: Please use proper code formatting

Comment: If "hello.py" is in a `PATH` directory, and running `hello 1 1` doesn't pass the command-line arguments, then the .py file association is broken. If CMD or PowerShell doesn't find "hello.py", then .PY isn't in `PATHEXT`. You should not need to run `python hello.py 1 1`. That's annoying since it requires using a qualified path for hello.py or changing to its directory first.

Answer (score 100):

- `import sys` out of hello function.
- arguments should be converted to int.
- String literal that contain `'` should be escaped or should be surrouned by `"`.
- Did you invoke the program with `python hello.py <some-number> <some-number>` in command line?

---

```
import sys

def hello(a,b):
    print "hello and that's your sum:", a + b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = int(sys.argv[1])
    b = int(sys.argv[2])
    hello(a, b)
```

Comment: `import` not in top-level - it's not recommended. Should be placed before `def hello`

Comment: Using `print` without parentheses is not advisable in Python 2.7. You should aim for compatibility with Python 3 ;)

Comment: @Agostino, `print('a', 'b')` will print `('a', 'b')` in Python 2.x, unlike Python 3.x which print `a b`. (unless you are using `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2.x)

Comment: It's not difficult to find a way to make it work for both. E.g. `print("hello and that's your sum: " + str(a + b))`

Comment: @Agostino, I would use `from __future__ import print_function` as I mentioned in previous comment if I really want to use `print` as a function :)  or `print("hello and that's your sum: %s" % (a+b))` or `print("hello and that's your sum: {}".format(a+b))`

Comment: With the solution I proposed, you don't need to import anything from `__future__`. In Python 2.7 you *can* use parentheses with `print`. As long as you print a single string and use `+` to concatenate substrings, you get the same behavior.

Comment: @Agostino, Same for string formatting operator (%), or `str.format`.

Comment: What about the int cast?

Comment: @Agostino, Without `int`, `sys.argv[...]` are strings.

Answer (score 34):

I found this thread looking for information about dealing with parameters; [this easy guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-easy-guide-to-python-command-line-arguments-96b4607baea1) was so cool:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script so useful.')
parser.add_argument("--opt1", type=int, default=1)
parser.add_argument("--opt2")

args = parser.parse_args()

opt1_value = args.opt1
opt2_value = args.opt2
```

runs like:

```
python myScript.py --opt2 = 'hi'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with the reference where well summaries the most common usage of py arguments.

Answer (score 17):

Here are all of the previous answers summarized:

- modules should be imported outside of functions.
- hello(sys.argv[2]) needs to be indented since it is inside an if statement.
- hello has 2 arguments so you need to call 2 arguments.
- as far as calling the function from terminal, you need to call python .py  ...

The code should look like this:

```
import sys
def hello(a, b):
    print "hello and that's your sum:"
    sum = a+b
    print sum

if __name__== "__main__":
    hello(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

Then run the code with this command:

```
python hello.py 1 1
```

Answer (score 15):

To execute your program from the command line, you have to call the python interpreter, like this :

```
C:\Python27>python hello.py 1 1
```

If you code resides in another directory, you will have to set the python binary path in your PATH environment variable, to be able to run it, too. You can find detailed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7).

Comment: Or just spell out python my_full_path\hello.py 1 1

Comment: thank you so much, I've also used it this way,I defined environment variables(PATH,path, and pathext),without success

Comment: Make sure to close and reopen the console you are using when you make a change to PATH.

Answer (score 5):

Your indentation is broken. This should fix it:

```
import sys

def hello(a,b):
    print 'hello and thats your sum:'
    sum=a+b
    print sum

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Obviously, if you put the `if __name__` statement **inside** the function, it will only ever be evaluated if you run that function. The problem is: the point of said statement is to run the function in the first place.

Comment: thank you so much for this code,it worked,but I'd like to know what really was wrong, and where to find more details about it please,thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

def hello(a, b):
    print  'hello and that\'s your sum: {0}'.format(a + b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

Moreover see @thibauts answer about how to call python script.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a couple of mistakes in the code.

1. 'import sys' line should be outside the functions as the function is itself being called using arguments fetched using sys functions.
2. If you want correct sum, you should cast the arguments (strings) into floats. Change the sum line to --> sum = float(a) + float(b).
3. Since you have not defined any default values for any of the function arguments, it is necessary to pass both arguments while calling the function --> hello(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[2])

   `import sys
    def hello(a,b):
      print ("hello and that's your sum:")
      sum=float(a)+float(b)
      print (sum)`

   `if __name__ == "__main__":
      hello(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])`

Also, using "C:\Python27>hello 1 1" to run the code looks fine but you have to make sure that the file is in one of the directories that Python knows about (PATH env variable). So, please use the full path to validate the code.
Something like:

```
C:\Python34>python C:\Users\pranayk\Desktop\hello.py 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the file .py association and you will be able to run scripts with arguments without having to call python.exe

- Run regedit.exe
- Look for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.py_auto_file\shell\open\command
- Add more arguments like: "D:\Python3\python.exe" "%1" "%2" "%3"

Then you can just use hello.py 1 1