# How to download twitter feed

Tags: python, twitter

I am quite the novice when it comes to coding.  How do I modify this sample code to download tweets using Python?

```
def get_tweets(api, input_query):
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=input_query, lang="en").items():
    yield tweet

if __name__ == "__version__":
    input_query = sys.argv[1]

    access_token = "REPLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE"
    access_token_secret = "REPLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE"
    consumer_key = "REPLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE"
    consumer_secret = "REPLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE"
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    tweets = get_tweets(api, input_query)
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
```

I entered my keys.

I should be able to download tweets using a command like this print_tweets.py "Enter subject here"
Where do I enter this command?  In Python? In the command prompt?

I am getting this error:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 print_tweets.py
>
> NameError: name 'print_tweets' is not defined

Please help!

Comment: looks like you need to include the "subject" after the script and yes, using the "command prompt", so something like : `python print_tweets.py springbreak`, etc, replacing "springbreak" with your "subject" to search. The `NameError` is telling you your command is missing that first argument `input_query = sys.argv[1]`

Comment: Also might need to change `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NameError` is saying the python script isn't receiving [command line arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv), `sys.argv[1]` being the "subject". Replace  "Enter subject here" with the subject you wish to search.

In this example, `springbreak` is `sys.argv[1]`:

```
C:\> python print_tweets.py springbreak
```

should return and print out tweet texts containing your "subject".

You may also need to change:

`if __name__ == "__version__":`

to

`if __name__ == "__main__":`

as `__main__` is the entry-point to the script.

The entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import tweepy

def get_tweets(api, input_query):
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=input_query, lang="en").items():
        yield tweet

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_query = sys.argv[1]

    access_token = "REPLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE"
    access_token_secret = "REPLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE"
    consumer_key = "REPLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE"
    consumer_secret = "REPLACE_YOUR_KEY_HERE"
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    tweets = get_tweets(api, input_query)
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you both!

So, when I try to run this in the command prompt I get this error message

C:\Users\X>print_tweets.py "subject"
'print_tweets.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What would cause this?

Comment: Try adding `python` before `print_tweets.py`, so the full command should have 3 parts: `python print_tweets.py subject`

Comment: Thank you.  Finally, should print_tweets.py work based on the script above?  How do I store the script as "print_tweets.py" so the command works?

Comment: The script above should be contained in a plain-text file with the `.py` extension. You can give the file any name you like, I gave the script the name `print_tweets.py` as in your question. Then the command `python print_tweets.py subject` should work. Here's a better explanation: [How do I run Python script using arguments in windows command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544307/how-do-i-run-python-script-using-arguments-in-windows-command-line)

Comment: You are a lifesaver.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Does it all make sense? If it worked, and my answer helped, please upvote it and click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it green [like this picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). If so, I'm very glad to help you, good luck! Cheers! :)