# Running python script from perl, with argument to stdin and saving stdout output

Tags: python, perl

My perl script is at path:

```
a/perl/perlScript.pl
```

my python script is at path:

```
a/python/pythonScript.py
```

`pythonScript.py` gets an argument from stdin, and returns result to stdout. From `perlScript.pl` , I want to run `pythonScript.py` with the argument `hi` to stdin, and save the results in some variable. That's what I tried:

```
my $ret = `../python/pythonScript.py < hi`;
```

but I got the following error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Can you explain the path can't be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`qx` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) (backticks) starts a shell (`sh`), in which `prog < input` syntax [expects a file](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) named `input` from which it will read lines and feed them to the program `prog`.  But you want the python script to receive on its `STDIN` the string `hi` instead, not lines of a file named `hi`.

One way is to directly do that, `my $ret = qx(echo "hi" | python_script)`.

But I'd suggest to consider using modules for this.  Here is a simple example with [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use IPC::Run3;

my @cmd = ('program', 'arg1', 'arg2');

my $in = "hi";

run3 \@cmd, \$in, \my $out;

say "script's stdout: $out";
```

The `program` is the path to your script if it is executable, or perhaps `python script.py`. This will be run by `system` so the output is obtained once that completes, what is consistent with the attempt in the question. See documentation for module's operation.

This module is intended to be simple while "*satisfy 99% of the need for using `system`, `qx`, and `open3 [...]`*. For far more power and control see [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.96/lib/IPC/Run.pm).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because you're using shell redirection instead of just passing an argument

```
../python/pythonScript.py < hi
```

tells your shell to read input from a file called hi in the current directory, rather than using it as an argument. What you mean to do is

```
my $ret = `../python/pythonScript.py hi`;
```

Which correctly executes your python script with the hi argument, and returns the result to the variable `$ret`.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The</s> Some of the other answers assume that `hi` must be passed as a command line parameter to the Python script but the asker says it comes from stdin.

Thus:

```
my $ret = `echo "hi" | ../python/pythonScript.py`;
```

Answer (score 0):

To launch your external script you can do

```
system "python ../python/pythonScript.py hi";
```

and then in your python script

```
import sys
def yourFct(a, b):
    ...

if __name__== "__main__":
    yourFct(sys.argv[1])
```

you can have more informations on the python part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544307/how-do-i-run-python-script-using-arguments-in-windows-command-line)