# something like $_GET in python...?

Tags: python

I'm really new to python (literally started today, 2 hours ago)...

I know php and i want to know if theres a method to introduce variables in to a .py file...

For example in php you have $_GET variable...
I want something like this...

`python myprogram.py --num 1234567890`

To be executed inside...

```
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('txtPhone')
search_box.send_keys('$num')
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('txtPhoneC')
search_box.send_keys('$num')
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='ddlProducts']/option[text()='10']").click()
```

How can i do that? (not english native speaker)

NOTE: I dont know if it matters, but im using selenium with chromedriver to make a "bot"

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544307/how-do-i-run-python-script-using-arguments-in-windows-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `argparse` module to parse command-line arguments:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--num', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then you can refer to the `num` parameter in your code with:

```
search_box.send_keys(args.num)
```

Please read argparse's documentation for details:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: and how can i put that --num into this: search_box.send_keys('$num') ...with what i replace $num?

Comment: You should replace `$num` with `args.num`. I've updated my answer to incorporate the parsed argument in your original code.