# Bash script loop on python variable

Tags: python, bash, loops

I'm trying to do a simple script, but I don't get how to pass a variable to the command that I need:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for i in 1 2 3
do
python -c 'print "a"*' $i
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to go on with your solution using `python -c`, you would have to remove the space:

```
#!/bin/bash 
for i in 1 2 3
do
  python -c 'print "a"*'$i
done
```

But the approach suggested by Asmox makes more sense to me (and it has nothing to do with the question where you pipe the standard output to).

Comment: You absolutely *do not* have to remove the space. You just have to quote the whole argument.

Comment: This is **also** one possibility. I suggested to remove the space, because this requires the least changes to the original code, compared to `python -c "print 'a'* $i"`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this topic will help:
[How do I run Python script using arguments in windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544307/how-do-i-run-python-script-using-arguments-in-windows-command-line)

Have you considered making a whole script? Like this one:

```
import sys

def f(a):
    print a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = int(sys.argv[1])
    f(a)
```

This example might seem overcomplicated, but I wanted to show you how to pass parameter from console to function

Comment: i need this to pipe to another file, the whole line would be something like "python -c 'print "a"* $i ' | ./example "

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the solution provided above and had to modify for python3+

*due to lack of sufficient points I am not allowed to make a comment, thats why I posted my solution separately*

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}
do
  python -c "print ('a'* ${i})"
done

output~>
a
aa
aaa
```