# How to execute/call on a .py file in command prompt?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I have written a .py file using Eclipse. I want to run that file in command prompt. How do I go about that? I'm running it on Windows.

I tried
    python D:\Python Work/class/src/hello.py
The error I received was python: can't open file 'D:\Python':[Errno 2] No such file or directory. Also 'D:\Python' is not the entire address that I had specified.

Python was already been added to the PATH. I tried doing cd[file directory] and then python file.py but that gave me the same error

Thanks

Comment: `python3 file.py`. (This assumes you have Python installed and in your path- you should also mention your OS)

Comment: About `python3` or about `file.py`? Are you in the same directory as the file? Please show the error message you get.

Comment: Can you show the exact command you use? (And edit these into the original question)

Comment: Have you added python to your PATH: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6318188/1047268

Comment: First, do `cd [the directory containing file.py]`. Then, do `python file.py`.

Comment: You need to show the actual command you used, instead of "folder name" etc. I'm guessing that it was something like `D:\Python projects`- that had a *space* in it.

Comment: Yes,it did. Does that cause a problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you are running on windows - either:

```
python "D:\\Folder name\\Project name\\src\\module name.py"
```

Or:

```
python "D:/Folder name/Project name/src/module name.py"
```

Your choice basically.

The rules for windows file names are:

Back slashes, `\` must be escaped by doubling to `\\` spaces **must** be inside of double quotes "like this" quotes and few others need to be escaped as well and the extension **does** matter so give it.