# Could not scan for classes inside folder which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

Tags: php, composer-php

Am trying to install [widgets and forms module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-widgets) via Composer. But for both i get the some error.

What can be problem?

> Could not scan for classes inside "cms//tests/behat/"

```
$ composer require silverstripe/widgets
Using version ^1.2 for silverstripe/widgets
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing silverstripe/widgets (1.2.2)
    Downloading: 100%

Writing lock file Generating autoload files

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [RuntimeException]   Could not scan for classes inside "cms//tests/behat/" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Composer error: "could not scan for classes inside dir"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595801/how-to-fix-composer-error-could-not-scan-for-classes-inside-dir)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like composer's autoloader is expecting to see a Behat directory structure which is not there. Look at this [post](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/62306?start=8) a similar issue there for which the solution is to delete any pre-composer installed modules and re-run `composer update`. If this is your dev environment, you can also delete your "vendor" directory, and re-run `composer update` or `composer install` as necessary.