# RuntimeException Could not scan for classes inside "app/AppKernel.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

Tags: php, git-bash

i want to ask, i get this message from git bash when i type this

`$ composer require slim/slim "^3.0"`  then appear warn like this.

```
[RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "app/AppKernel.php" which does not appear
   to be a file nor a folder
```

Can you help me guys ? sorry for bad english.

Thank you.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: We need your OS version and composer version....

Comment: Windows 8 and my composer is the lastest version.

Comment: Farkie, I 've tried it your way, but it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

This answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/42934196/2110663

Check your `composer.json` file for occurencies **app/AppKernel.php**, and check your file structrue to be sure that you have this file in path.
In my case i had next part in composer.json (see classmap)

```
 ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
 ...
```

I tried to build dockerfile and cache at first vendors without code dependency. So
My dockerfile looks next

```
...
ADD composer.json .
ADD composer.lock .
RUN composer install
...
```

In this case filesystem does not contain app/AppKernel.php file, but composer.json file required for it.
To resolve this issue we have 2 options:

1. Update `composer.json` and remove from it mentions of problematic files
2. Add files, or check its existence in file-system

My solution was to add absent files before running `composer install`. Updated Dockerfile looks next:

```
ADD composer.json .
ADD composer.lock .
# Fix composer install issue with adding 2 lines below
ADD app/AppKernel.php app/
ADD app/AppCache.php app/

RUN composer install
```

Hope this hint might helps for somebody else