# Laravel - RuntimeException - Composer Install

Tags: php, laravel, runtimeexception

I am trying to install composer but then got this Exception. 
How could I overcome this problem? 
Thanks in advance!

> [RuntimeException] Could not scan for classes inside
>   "/Users/maximprimak/Desktop/BetaSite/vendor/sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup/src/"
>   which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

Comment: well does this location even exists, and if so is it writable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Composer error: "could not scan for classes inside dir"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595801/how-to-fix-composer-error-could-not-scan-for-classes-inside-dir)

Comment: please share your composer.json file

Comment: can you please share the command that you wrote to install composer ? 

where do you run this command ? inside the root folder of laravel project ?

Comment: If you have a composer.lock file try deleting it and running `composer install` again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I solved this problem just by deleting the Vendor folder and then install the composer again.

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall the composer.

```
command :: composer install
```