# How to avoid "Could not scan for classes inside" error with Composer?

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

(I know others have [written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595801/how-to-fix-composer-error-could-not-scan-for-classes-inside-dir) about this, but the answers don't seem to help in this instance)

I have a WordPress PHP plugin (https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages/) which uses [WDS-Shortcodes](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/WDS-Shortcodes) which in turn uses [TGM-Plugin-Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/). When I run `composer install` from within the lqd-messages plugin I get the following error:

> In ClassMapGenerator.php line 69:
>
> Could not scan for classes inside "`/lqd-messages/vendor/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes/vendor/tgmpa/tgm-plugin-activation/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php`" which does not appear to be a file or folder"

I can then go into `/lqd-messages/vendor/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes/vendor` and see that there is no tgmpa folder.

If I then go back to `/wds-shortcodes` and run `composer install`, the tgmpa folder will be successfully created.

Obviously, this is less than ideal. Is there a way to get around these extra steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug in `webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes` package - their [autoloadig settings](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/WDS-Shortcodes/blob/456dc14909a4295dcc5cf1befae441fc4762cb29/composer.json#L25-L28) are incorrect. Dependencies should not declare loading files from other dependencies inside of `vendor` directory - this is not their concern (and these files will not exist in some scenarios, like yours).

I can only recommend forking this package and fixing autoloading settings:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["includes/"]
},
```

---

BTW: You've made the same mistake in [your package](https://github.com/LiquidChurch/lqd-messages/blob/0d920949136758f94ccc4c2c07c56930b47a2b64/composer.json#L21-L30).

Comment: Thanks! I guess my question is, how do I ensure then that the tgmpa plugin is loaded if not using the autoloader?

Comment: You can use autoloader from Composer, you just should not declare autoloading files from `vendor` directory. Each package should define autoloading only for its own files - Composer will combine autoloading from all installed packages.

Comment: Thanks! I did as you suggested and I've progressed. I'm still getting one more error, hoping you can help me with. wds-shortcodes requires jtsternberg/shortcode-button (I removed the automap). But even with this removed I'm getting an error when trying to run phpunit: "`/long/path/lqd-messages/vendor/php un /long/path/lqd-messages/vendor/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes/vendor/jtsternberg/shortcode-button/shortcode-button.php on line 97`".