# How do you install glpk-solver along with pyomo in Winpython

Tags: python, installation, solver, glpk, pyomo

I want to use "pyomo" for my studies. I installed pyomo via `easy_install`
[coopr install instructions](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/downloader/download/file/64/CooprInstallGuide.pdf), Pyomo needs a solver to work so I wanted to install the 
(GNU Linear Programming Kit) [glpk_webpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), pyomo seems to be installed just right because I can import it in spyder (i am using WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3) with
`import coopr.pyomo`

However, I cannot do anything without glpk I guess...

I downloaded glpk-4.52 (latest version) from the ftp server but I do not know what to do with the batch files I found in the "w64"-folder I should use(?) according to "[Installing GLPK](http://holderfamily.dot5hosting.com/aholder/teach/courses/winter2010/OR/coopr/)"

I do not have Visual Studio installed - Isn't it possible to work without it?

Answer (score 9):

I recently installed GLPK for use with python 3.5 and pyomo under windows 7 and would like to report how I succeeded. I installed pyomo via:

```
pip install pyomo
```

Then, download WinGLPK 4.55 from here: [WinGLPK](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk/files/winglpk/GLPK-4.55/winglpk-4.55.zip/download)
This does not work for newer versions at the moment.
Unzip it and copy the whole w64 folder to `C:\w64`
Include folder `C:\w64` in your system PATH (so that `glpsol.exe` is found).

Check your installation using the simple example from the official pyomo documentation:

```
pyomo solve abstract1.py abstract1.dat --solver=glpk
```

The files abstract1.py and abstract1.dat can also be found in the pyomo documentation.

I hope this will help the next desperate GLPK installer.

Comment: WinGLPK 4.6.5 can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk/files/winglpk/GLPK-4.65/

Comment: For `Pyomo '6.4.2'`: `Pyomo only supports versions of GLPK since 4.58; found version 4.55.0.0.  Please upgrade your installation of GLPK`. So, use newer GLPK.

Answer (score 5):

FYI, you can now use Coopr without installing local solvers.  The latest Coopr release supports an interface with the NEOS solver. For example, if your MILP model is in the file `model.py`, then the following command would optimize the model using CBC:

```
pyomo --solver-manager=neos --solver=cbc model.py
```

Comment: Could you give us extra example on how to call it inside Python script?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Anaconda, both pyomo and glpk can be installed with conda install.  In the Windows terminal, activate your conda environment, then:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyomo
conda install -c conda-forge glpk
```

To test the glpk installation:

```
glpsol --help
```

Comment: Any time I need to run my first optimization in Windows, I have lots of issues; Thanks, this helped (I also did copy glpk in my C drive and add it to the PATH as well; did these before I saw your comment when I was testing other ways).

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never: in order to use GLPK (executable `glpsol.exe`), it must be somewhere on your sytem environment variable "Path". For sake of an example, let's assume you put the GLPK executable into the folder `C:\GLPK\bin`. Then (steps copied from [this answer by melhosseiny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318188/2375855)):

1. Hold <kbd>Win</kbd> and press <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
2. Click Advanced System Settings.
3. Click Environment Variables.
4. Append `;C:\GLPK\bin`to the `Path` variable.
5. Restart command prompt.

Now try to launch `glpsol` from any directory. If it is found, pyomo should now be able to use it.

Comment: Because I like to keep things better organized, I use to create the environment variable `%GLPK_HOME%` (which is a common practice) with the value of the path (e.g. `C:\glpk\w64`), then add this variable to the system's `%PATH%`.