# Unable to find ipopt.exe wheh downloaded using conda forge

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pyomo, ipopt

I have just downloaded anaconda from it's [web page for windows](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). H have installed pyomo using [conda forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyomo), also [ipopt](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ipopt). However, when I run a pyomo program which uses ipopt as solver, I get the following error.

```
    WARNING: Could not locate the 'ipopt' executable, which is required for solver
    ipopt
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\UX490U\informe_1\modelo_avion_bueno\07_10_2020_raw_pp_comparison\12h_horizon\2018_12h_jan_oct\noviembre\ECMWF\nov_EC.py", line 536, in <module>
    results = opt.solve(modelA,keepfiles=keepfiles,tee=stream_solver)

  File "C:\Users\UX490U\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 516, in solve
    self.available(exception_flag=True)

  File "C:\Users\UX490U\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 118, in available
    raise ApplicationError(msg % self.name)

ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'
```

I have gone to solver\shellcmd.py and I have read it, I see the line

```
from pyomo.opt.base.solvers import *
```

But I don't know if this is what should look like.

I need help to understand what is going on and what I can do.

Comment: I had a similar issue with another solver. The solution found here to add the .exe location to your sys path worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316069/pyomo-cant-locate-glpk-solver

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot find the .exe location. When I download it, I have searched using the file explorer, but there is no ipopt.exe

Comment: Maybe this issue is relevant: https://github.com/conda-forge/ipopt-feedstock/issues/55

Comment: @slow_learner I have the same issue, and have been at it for some time now. Had you found a solution you remember ? (ik, it's been 3 years ... )

Comment: I'm afraid I did not fix this. Sorry