# Pyomo: Access Solution From Python Code

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pyomo

I have a linear integer programme I want to solve. I installed solver glpk (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690195/how-do-you-install-glpk-solver-along-with-pyomo-in-winpython/37918417#37918417)) and pyomo. I wrote code like this:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

a = 370
b = 420
c = 2

model             = ConcreteModel()
model.x           = Var([1,2], domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.Objective   = Objective(expr = a * model.x[1] + b * model.x[2], sense=minimize)
model.Constraint1 = Constraint(expr = model.x[1] + model.x[2] == c)
# ... more constraints

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')

results = opt.solve(model)
```

This produces solution to file `results.yaml`.

I have many problems I want to solve using the same model but with different `a`, `b`, and `c` values. I want to assign different values to `a`, `b`, and `c`, solve the model, obtain solution of `model.x[1]` and `model.x[2]`, and have a listing of `a`, `b`, `c`, `model.x[1]` and `model.x[2]`. I read [documentation](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoOnlineDocs.html#_a_simple_concrete_pyomo_model) but examples only write solutions to file such as `results.yaml`.

Is there any way I can access to solution values from code?

Thanks,

Comment: Di not use this lib in a while. Can't you just access model.x.value? And also model.Objective.value.

Comment: @sascha, thanks. I tried `for i in model.x: print(model.x[i].value)`, and it worked.

Comment: @sascha, also it would be nice if you tell me why I should not use this lib. You mean [WinGLPK](http://winglpk.sourceforge.net/), right?

Comment: I did not recommend not using it. I hate the interface, but pyomo is super-powerful. There are not much alternatives. [cvxpy](www.cvxpy.org), if you stick to convex-programming (it constructs provable convex-programs by internal reasoning at a cost; it's also more matrix/math-ops based; it supports many nice functions out of the box like norms). There is also [pulp](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp). This one is doing MIP-only i think. It's more array-based but easier than pyomo. @ken_a

Comment: Okay, thanks. I tried others but in many cases I could not even install them. Pyomo/WinGLPK is so far the only library that I could install and get my job done. For now, I stick with it.

Comment: That's ok if it works for you. Pyomo should be very robust and seems to be the one which powers the most *industrial* applications (it's there for some years). It's also the only good one supporting MINLP and co. cvxpy is more modern and research-driven (convex only; not nice to install on Windows). pulp was always easy to install as i recall and it brings a better MIP-solver out of the box (cbc > glpk in my opinion). The only problem of pyomo (besides the interface) is the documentation. cvxpy shines here, while pulp is simple enough (that the docs available are enough). @ken_a

Comment: And one more remark: if you are working in academics, where the commercial solvers sometimes are free to use: [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/) (and [Mosek](https://www.mosek.com/); no Integer-programming support i think) both bring good python-interfaces (which are still evolving). These are mostly comparable to pulps approach. These should be the most stable and most documented. But, formulated once, only one solver is accepted. @ken_a

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this is a way that I have some variables being printed in one of my scripts.

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
from pyomo.core import Var

M = AbstractModel()
opt = SolverFactory('glpk')

# Vars, Params, Objective, Constraints....

instance = M.create_instance('input.dat') # reading in a datafile
results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True)
results.write()
instance.solutions.load_from(results)

for v in instance.component_objects(Var, active=True):
    print ("Variable",v)
    varobject = getattr(instance, str(v))
    for index in varobject:
        print ("   ",index, varobject[index].value)
```

Comment: thank you. I put the for loop in my code with my variables in it, and it shows values I wanted t access!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this loops over all defined variables... I dunno. I found it after digging through the poor Pyomo documentation a few years back :)

Comment: It does. I have tried it.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a modified version of your script that illustrates two different ways of printing variable values:  (1) by explicitly referencing each variable and (2) by iterating over all variables in the model.

```
# Pyomo v4.4.1
# Python 2.7
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

a = 370
b = 420
c = 4

model             = ConcreteModel()
model.x           = Var([1,2], domain=Binary)
model.y           = Var([1,2], domain=Binary)
model.Objective   = Objective(expr = a * model.x[1] + b * model.x[2] + (a-b)*model.y[1] + (a+b)*model.y[2], sense=maximize)
model.Constraint1 = Constraint(expr = model.x[1] + model.x[2] + model.y[1] + model.y[2] <= c)

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')

results = opt.solve(model)

#
# Print values for each variable explicitly
#
print("Print values for each variable explicitly")
for i in model.x:
  print str(model.x[i]), model.x[i].value
for i in model.y:
  print str(model.y[i]), model.y[i].value
print("")

#
# Print values for all variables
#
print("Print values for all variables")
for v in model.component_data_objects(Var):
  print str(v), v.value
```

Here's the output generated:

```
Print values for each variable explicitly
x[1] 1.0
x[2] 1.0
y[1] 0.0
y[2] 1.0

Print values for all variables
x[1] 1.0
x[2] 1.0
y[1] 0.0
y[2] 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the `pyomoio` module in the [urbs project](https://github.com/tum-ens/urbs/blob/master/urbs/pyomoio.py). It extracts sets, parameters, variables, and so on, and the returns them in `pandas` objects, which are very convenient for visualization in jupyter notebooks.

I build a simple model

```py
model = ConcreteModel()
model.act = Set(initialize=list('IJK'))
model.goods = Set(initialize=list('ijk'))
u0 = {}
u0['i', 'J'] = 2.
u0['k', 'I'] = .3
model.U0 = Param(model.goods, model.act, initialize=u0, default=0)
```

I can then read it in a pandas DataFrame, with all the labels set appropriately.

```py
import pyomoio as po
u_df = po.get_entity(model, 'U0').unstack()
print(u_df)

# act      I    J    K
# goods               
# i      0.0  2.0  0.0
# j      0.0  0.0  0.0
# k      0.3  0.0  0.0
```