# How can I acces to my results from a class solution with pyomo?

Tags: python, class, instance, pyomo

I just want to explain that I'm super new to python 
I want to acces the results from my problem:

I have this, and its running I just want to access my  results so that I can compare the two types of batteries that I have
How can I have the Results for B1 and for B2 that  is being solved for?

Here is one of my variables declared:

```
model.ach = Var(model.t , domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0,1)) #Rate of charging
```

Here is a dictonary to build the demand

```
demand = Jan[:24*4*5]
t = range(len(demand))
demand_dict = {}
for tt, dd in zip(t, demand):
demand_dict[tt] = dd
```

Here is declared fixed values:

```
 cosP = 12.34
 cosE=0.0606
 cosF=0.02673
```

After my objective function is  declared in my abstract model I use a class to have different kinds of Batteries:

```
class Battery:
      def __init__(self, n, Emax, Emin, cap):
      self.n=n
      self.Emax=Emax
      self.Emin=Emin
     self.cap=cap


B1=Battery(0.8,3800,400,500)
B2=Battery(0.8,7600,800,1000)
Batts=[B1,B2]
```

Now I'm interating through the two classes my model

```
Results=[]
Instance=[]
for b in Batts:
        data = {None: {'cosP': {None: cosP},
               't': {None: t},
               'cosE': {None: cosE},
               'cosF':{None:cosF},
               'n':{None: b.n},
               'Emax':{None:b.Emax}, #kWh max capacity
               'Emin':{None:b.Emin}, #kWh min capacity
               'cap':{None:b.cap},
               'dem': demand_dict
              }
        }
        instance=model.create_instance(data)
        opt=SolverFactory('glpk')
        results = opt.solve(instance)
Results.append(results)
Instance.append(instance)
```

I'm, trying to access for example a value previously delcared ach I tried this:

```
for t in instance.t:
    ach.append(instance.ach[t].value)
```

But that only gives me acces to the last runt i.e b2 in Battery. How do I access other values assuming I might have multiples b's

Comment: Hi, I think you need to fix the indentation in your question, it will make it much easier to understand what your are trying to do. I assume the last 5 lines should be part of the for loop.

Also, you should clarify _what_ results (i.e. what variables) you are trying to look at, and what they are indexed on.

Comment: Hi Giorgio, you are right, I'm trying to access dem from Battery 1 or 2. I know how to do it without a Class defyining my batteries, but since I have multiple batteries i dont want to have this code multiple times, thank you :)

Comment: Is `results = opt.solve(instance)` on the same indentation than `Results.append(results)`? If they are the way they are, only the last `results` and the last `instance` will be added to your `Results` and `Instance` lists. Also, you would need to add another `for` block at the top of your `for t in instance.t:`, to have something like `for instance in Instance:`, if you want to run the action in your `for`block for all saved instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get the result of one of your variable, simply do

```
print(instance.X[indice1, indice2].value) #for indexed var objects
```

or

```
print(instance.X.value) #for non-indexed var objects
```

where `indice1` and `indice2` are the indices that is part of your variable index, and where `X` is the name of your variable.

The use of `print` is only to show the result, and the value of your variable can be used in Python directly if you don't use `print`.

Edit: If you want to access the value of all variables, I recommend you the following question: [Pyomo: Access Solution From Python Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700214/pyomo-access-solution-from-python-code)

Comment: Hi Brunelle: so in indice1, indice2 will be class?

Comment: More like an index of a `dict`.

Comment: Indexes can a reference to an instances of object, but I doubt this makes a clear notation. How did you define your model variables?

Comment: If I try to access a variable  i.e. named  ach this is what optimizing for so its a `Var(model.t)` , I'm not quite sure if this is what you mean

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I don't know if your variables are indexed or not. If they are, I want to give you a complete notation. And if they are indexed by instances of `Battery`, without name, only class reference, then I think you will get funny indexes.

Comment: Maybe, you can show us how your model variables are instantiated by editing your question a little bit. This would really help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient, I just added more information