# Sublime2 and SublimeREPL

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

Using Windows 7, Python 3.2 and Sublime Text 2

I went through all of the instruction to install SublimeREPL and when I go to `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python -> Python` I get an error: "WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file speificed.'). I went to the FAQ and added the following (exactly as stated) to the user preferences:

```
{
 ...
"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "C:/Python32"}
 ...
}`
```

When I try to save the file I get another error: "Error trying to parse setting: Expected value in..." and it points to the SublimeREPL file.

The entire file is the generic version that comes with the install:

```
{
// default_extend_env are used to augment any environment variables
// that should be visible for all subprocess repls launched within
// SublimeREPL. This is a very good place to add PATH extension
// once "PATH": "{PATH}:/home/username/mylocalinstalls/bin" or whatever
"default_extend_env": {},

// Specify whether to move repls to a different Sublime Text group (frame)
// immediately on opening. Setting this to true will simply move it to
// the 'next' group from the one that was in focus when it was opened
// (one down with row layout, one to the right with column and grid
// layout). Alternatively, you can set this to the index of the group in
// which you want all repls to be opened (index 0 being the top-left group).
// Activating this option will NOT automatically change your layout/create
// a new group if it isn't open.
"open_repl_in_group": true,

// Persistent history is stored per REPL external_id, it means that all python
// REPLS will share history. If you wish you can disable history altogether
"persistent_history_enabled": true,

// By default SublimeREPL leaves REPL view open once the underlying subprocess
// dies or closes connection. This is useful when the process dies for an unexpected
// reason as it allows you to inspect it output. If you want. Setting this
// to true will cause SublimreREPL to close view once the process died.
"view_auto_close": false,

// Some terminals output ascii color codes which are not currently supported
// enable this option to filter them out.
"filter_ascii_color_codes": true,

// Where to look for python virtualenvs
"python_virtualenv_paths": [
    "~/.virtualenvs",  // virtualenvwrapper
    "~/.venv"  // venv.bash https://github.com/wuub/venv
],

// Use arrows for history navigation instead of Alt+[P|N]/Ctrl+[P|N]
"history_arrows": true,

// standard sublime view settings that will be overwritten on each repl view
// this has to be customized as a whole dictionary
"repl_view_settings": {
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "auto_indent": false,
    "smart_indent": false,
    "spell_check": false,
    "indent_subsequent_lines": false,
    "detect_indentation": false,
    "auto_complete": true,
    "line_numbers": false,
    "gutter": false
},

// this settings exposes additional variables in repl config files, especially
// those related to sublime projects that are not available through standard API
// WARNING: this will switch your build system back to Automatic each time a REPL
// is started so beware!
"use_build_system_hack": false,

// IP address used to setup autocomplete server in sublimerepl.
// changing this is usefull when you want to exclude one address
// from proxychains/tsocks routing
"autocomplete_server_ip": "127.0.0.1",

// Mapping is used, when external_id of REPL does not match
// source.[xxx] scope of syntax definition used to highlight
// files from which text is being transfered. For example octave
// repls use source.matlab syntax files and w/o this mapping text transfer
// will not work
"external_id_mapping": {
    "octave": "matlab"
},

// If set to true, SublimeREPL will try to append evaluated code to repl
// output before evaluation (e.g. Ctrl+, f)
"show_transferred_text": false
```

}

I am trying to evaluate selected code in Sublime2 with Python.

The above is what I added to the user file (SublimeREPL.sublime-settings - User). There is nothing else in the file besides what I added.

Comment: Are you getting the error "Error trying to parse setting..." when you're saving the python script or the user preferences file?

Comment: please [edit] your question and post your entire `SublimeREPL.sublime-settings` file so we can see what the error might be.

Comment: @AshokaLella I get it saving down the user file

Comment: @MattDMo Example added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sublime REPL picks up python from windows system path by default. You can set this path by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

In case you want to make changes in **SublimeREPL.sublime-settings** you need to change your line to

```
"default_extend_env": {"PATH":"{PATH};c:\\Python32"},
```

1. Since you're in windows you'll need to save '\' character from escaping using '\\'
2. The ***SublimeREPL.sublime-settings** is a JSON file so it expects ',' at the end
3. The **"{PATH};"** part is optional. It allows you to add python path to your existing path instead of overriding it.

Comment: When I run R same thing happens, so does this mean I have to manually switch the path every time?

Comment: you'll need to modify `{"PATH":"{PATH};c:\\Python32"}` to `{"PATH":"{PATH};c:\\Python32;c:\\path\\to\\R"}`