# Running web server using Python errors

Tags: python, command-line

I am using [this tutorial](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch04.html#_terminal_with_python) and specifically having trouble with the part that says:

"To run a Python web server:
Open up a new terminal window.
Via the command line, navigate into the directory that you want served. For example, if your project folder is in your Desktop folder on your Mac, you could type: cd ~/Desktop/project-folder.
Enter python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &.
"

But when I try that, it says "python" is not recognized as an internal or external command. Is there something I need to be adding to a PATH variable or something?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have python installed? It's a pretty dumb question but I still gotta ask

Comment: Good question! I do. At least, I think I do. When I type 'Python' into the Windows start bar something comes up saying 'Python (command line)' and I click on it and it takes me to a command prompt with C:\Python27\python.exe in the title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work on Windows just the same, try

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
```

If you want to be able to call it with simply `python ...`, see e.g. [Adding Python Path on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7) or [Installing Python 2.7 on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372637/installing-python-2-7-on-windows-8) for adding Python to Windows PATH.