# How to run a python code on sublime text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

i tried to run my code on windows 8 using ctrl+B but it gave the following error.

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\vishal_pc\Documents\python_codes\helloworld.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\vishal_pc\Documents\python_codes]
[path: c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\]
```

some body please help!
thank you.

Comment: Do you have Python installed?

Comment: yes i have installed python3.3 in my system.

Comment: It may be installed but it's install dir (where python.exe is located) seems not to be in PATH.

Comment: how to correct the path then?

Comment: @user3275284: Maybe google for that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your PATH isn't setup correctly.  Sometimes this happens when you install Python in a specific folder instead of the default C:\Python folder (e.g. C:\Python27)

To setup your PATH, right click on 'My Computer' and click 'Properties', then in the 'System Properties' click on the 'Advanced' tab.  In the 'System variables' section, you'll see a variable called 'Path'.  Now add where you installed Python to that list (additional items are appended with a semicolon).

For example, if you installed on C:\Program Files\Python27 then you would add ";C:\Program Files\Python27" to your PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to fix it easily [For Pyhton 3.X]
1. Uninstall current version 
1. Reinstall 
Note : Make Sure You Allow the Check box as Shown in the figure [Based on 3.7]

... [image]