# How to run Python from Sublime Text 3 on USB

Tags: python

How do I route PATH to USB?  Is there a way to do this? In other words...tell sublimetext to run python.exe off the USB.   Assuming no windows admin privilege.

This is in reference to the following question.

[How to run a python code on sublime text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578149/how-to-run-a-python-code-on-sublime-text-3)

Thank you,

Richard

Comment: USB means any flash storage?

Comment: please specify what you mean by USB

Comment: Yes, flash drive.  So I want to run everything portable just like Portable Python (discontinued).