# Trying to install crc16, not detecting Python

Tags: python, installation, crc16

I've got Python 2.7 (64-bit) installed and I'm trying to install `crc16`. I downloaded the relevant `crc16` Python 2.7 installation file:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crc16/0.1.1#downloads

When I try and install it, however, it says that I don't have Python 2.7 installed and it doesn't see it in the registry. Looking in my C drive I can see that I absolutely have a folder for Python2.7. Am I having this issue because `crc16` is 32-bit? How can I get `crc16` to install correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does look like they're only providing installers for 32-bit Python. You'll probably have to either build it yourself or convince the maintainers to build for 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I missed the part where it had to be compiled. It looks like the developer only made a 32 bit version for Windows. You could try using a 32 bit version of Python

Comment: Yep. The issue was using 64bit python over 32 bit. I switched over to 32bit Python and now things are working.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add the location of the Python executable to your PATH environment variable.

1. Right click My computer and go to properties
2. Click Advanced System Settings.
3. Click Environment Variables.
4. Append ;C:\python27 to the Path variable.
5. Restart Command Prompt.

This is based on the answer from [Adding Python Path on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Comment: No luck there. ;C:\Python27 was already part of my system variables. I tried adding it to my user variables but it still didn't work.