# "ImportError: No module named httplib2" even after installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, httplib2

I'm having a hard time understanding why I get `ImportError: No module named httplib2` after making sure httplib2 *is* installed. See below:

```
$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python 

$ pip -V
pip 1.4.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7

$ pip list
google-api-python-client (1.2)
httplib2 (0.8)
pip (1.4.1)
pudb (2013.5.1)
Pygments (1.6)
setuptools (1.3.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)

$ pip install httplib2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2013, 21:33:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named httplib2
```

I've also done

```
$ find / | grep httplib2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py
[... edited for brevity]
```

PLUMBING! >shakes fist at heavens<

Comment: Can you do a `which python` too?

Comment: ahhh... i seeeeeeee....

Comment: well, looks like pip is installing my libraries for the second of the python installations, so when I run python, it doesn't find the installed modules. evidenced by `$ /usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Dec 27 2013, 14:07:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib
>>>`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

added this to .bash_profile
`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

then got:

```
$ which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Dec 27 2013, 14:07:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib2
>>>
```

can't say for sure why `pip` was installing to `/usr/local` instead of system default, but now they're the same, so it's working for now.

Answer (score 51):

If there are multiple Python instances (2 & 3), try different `pip`, for example:

Python 2:

```
pip2 install httplib2 --upgrade
```

Python 3:

```
pip3 install httplib2 --upgrade
```

To check what's installed and where, try:

```
pip list
pip2 list
pip3 list
```

Then make sure you're using the right Python instance (as suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735731/55075)).

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problems on Windows 7.
Here is how I solved it:

1. Install Python: Simply [download Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and follow the installation instructions of the wizard.
2. Now, Python should be accessible from the command line. However, in my case, calling

   py script.py
   resulted in the the same error: "ImportError: No module named httplib2"
3. I then had to add the Python and Pip installation paths to the "Path" environment variable in order to install the httplib2 module and then execute the script without failure.
   I followed the instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318188/4419882).
4. Then I was able to execute

   pip3 install httplib2 --upgrade
5. In the end I successfully managed to execute the script containing the httplib2 import statement.

Answer (score 3):

**On Ubuntu:**

Installing the library using the Ubuntu package manager fixed my issue:

```
sudo apt-get install python-httplib2
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above work, you can see which paths a specific python is checking with `sys.path`:

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib64/python37.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.7', '/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

If the lib is already immediately under one of these paths, check its permissions as pip may have installed it with only root owner and group permissions:

```
$ sudo ls -FsCla /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
total 8
0 drwxr-x---. 13 root root  274 Jun  5 14:06 ./
0 drwxr-x---.  3 root root   27 Jun  5 14:02 ../
4 drwxr-x---.  3 root root 4096 Jun  5 14:02 requests/
0 drwxr-x---.  2 root root  102 Jun  5 14:02 requests-2.23.0.dist-info/

$ sudo ls -FsCla /usr/local/lib/python3.7
total 0
0 drwxr-x---.  3 root root  27 Jun  5 14:02 ./
0 drwxr-x---.  3 root root  23 Jun  5 14:02 ../
0 drwxr-x---. 13 root root 274 Jun  5 14:06 site-packages/
```

Here's one way to fix it quickly:

```
$ sudo find /usr/local/lib/python3.7 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
$ sudo find /usr/local/lib/python3.7 -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

Or you can use a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

For me, after using `pip install` I used `pip list` to check where the module was installed. Then, I went to that directory in terminal and ran `` export PYTHONPATH=`pwd` `` , that fixed it