# httplib2 not working when calling python script from PHP

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, php-7

I am trying to execute my python code from PHP application. But I am getting the below mentioned error when I try to execute from my PHP application. It works fine when running directly on the shell.

PHP: `shell_exec( $scriptToCall . " 2>&1" );`

Env:

1. Python3
2. PHP 7
3. Ubuntu

Error:

> ImportError: No module named 'httplib2'

I followed this link to - ["ImportError: No module named httplib2" even after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735496/importerror-no-module-named-httplib2-even-after-installation)

also, pip list shows httplib2 installed.

Comment: did you read this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735496/importerror-no-module-named-httplib2-even-after-installation

Comment: @parik I had followed this as well. But issue not resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely, httplib2 is not globally installed for all users, but installed for your user specifically. you say `It works fine when running directly on the shell` but don't specify which user, assuming you mean `it works fine when i run it from MY OWN USER ACCOUNT`, try running it from the same user account as your php script runs in, then you'll probably get the same error. in debian/ubuntu & co , it's by default `sudo su www-data -s /bin/bash`, in arch it's by default `sudo su http -s /bin/bash` to enter those accounts - and solution is to either globally install httplib2 or install it specifically for the php user account