# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip' in spite of an installation

Tags: python, pip, pyperclip

Windows 10, python 3.6.4
I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'` when i run a program.

When I type `pip list` and `pip freeze` in command prompt `pyperclip (1.6.0)` is shown as installed.

When I type `pip install pyperclip` in command prompt I get `Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\python\lib\site-packages`.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide: a) full traceback when you do `python -c "import pyperclip"` or run when running a script with `import pyperclip` b) output of `print(sys.path)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ImportError: No module named httplib2" even after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735496/importerror-no-module-named-httplib2-even-after-installation)

Comment: Do you have multiple Python installations?

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem too! and i solved running:
`python -m pip install pyperclip`

> note: replace for python that is being used, for example, if you are
> trying running in python 3.10: `python3.10 -m pip install pyperclip`

this problem may is because you may more than one python environment which one of then have no pyperclip installed