# Install gplearn

Tags: python, visual-studio-2019, gplearn

I try to install GPLearn to run in Python.

I have used pip to install GPLearn by the command:

```
pip install gplearn
```

Everything seems to work fine

When starting a new python project in VS2019 and running the code

```
import gplearn
print('ok')
```

This gives the error No module named 'gplearn'.

Tried the exact same approach with Scikit-learn and it worked just fine.

Comment: make sure the runtime pip installed gplearn is the same runtime used in vs2019;

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the version of pip used to install gplearn is not the same version of python you are using in VS2019.

Try the top answer found here: ["ImportError: No module named httplib2" even after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735496/importerror-no-module-named-httplib2-even-after-installation)

Comment: That can actually be the problem! Python version for VS2019 are 3.7 and if I'm running "python" in command prompt it states 3.6.4.

Comment: Now I have reinstalled everything, Python (+ pip), gplearn (+ dependencies) and unfortunately, I still get the same error. The version of python is now 3.7.3, however.

Comment: Is it possible you need to change the python environment?  Check out this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2019)