# Git Bash won't run my python files?

Tags: python, windows, git, bash

I have been trying to run my python files in Git Bash but I keep getting an error and can't figure out how to fix it. My command as follows in the git bash executable `python filename.py` then it says

```
"Bash.exe": python.exe: command not found
```

I'm a windows user and I have added the path to my environment variables like so `C:\Python27\python.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`

I have been looking around but I can't find anyone that has had this problem or they don't give a straightforward answer please help.

Also I have never used Git before this is my first time.

Comment: Could you type `echo $PATH` and paste the results? You may be using the Windows Environment variables instead of the ones that Bash recognizes

Comment: Your PATH should contain the directories containing your executables, not the executables themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Python Path on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7)

Comment: If you run `python` in the terminal, it should (now) come up with the Windows Store app installation page.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Adapting the `PATH` should work. Just tried on my Git bash:

```
$ python --version
sh.exe": python: command not found

$ PATH=$PATH:/c/Python27/

$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

In particular, only provide the directory; don't specify the `.exe` on the `PATH` ; and use slashes.

Comment: No it doesn't work. It is not enough to have Python executable dir in PATH. It still doesn't work

Comment: @Green: Given the number of upvotes, I'd say that it might have been pretty effective so far. ie: I think you're in a particular case here (custom bash? python installed in a path with whitespaces?). Hence I'd suggest you ask a new question, so you'll be able to give as much details as possible, in order to get a more accurate reply for your particular case

Comment: this works for me. Any way to automatically do this every time I open up git bash instead of having to rewrite this every time? EDIT: other answer below explains how to add to bash rc

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso see the second answer below to make the path change permament: `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/c/Python27" ' > .profile`

Answer (score 26):

That command did not work for me, I used:

```
$ export PATH="$PATH:/c/Python27"
```

Then to make sure that git remembers the python path every time you open git type the following.

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/c/Python27"' > .profile
```

Answer (score 12):

**Here is the SOLUTION**

**If you get Response:**

1. `bash: python: command not found` OR
2. `bash: conda: command not found`

**To the following Commands:**
when you execute `python` or `python -V` `conda` or `conda --version` in your Git/Terminal window

**Background:** This is because you either

1. Installed Python in a location on your C Drive (C:) which is not
   directly in your program files folder.
2. Installed Python maybe on the D Drive (D:) and your computer by
       default searches for it on your C:
3. You have been told to go to your environment variables (located if you do a search for environment variables on your machines start menu) and change the "Path" variable on your computer and this still does not fix the problem.

**Solution:**

1. At the command prompt, paste this command `export PATH="$PATH:/c/Python36"`. That will tell Windows where to find Python. (This assumes that you installed it in C:\Python36)
2. If you installed python on your D drive, paste this command `export PATH="$PATH:/d/Python36"`.
3. Then at the command prompt, paste `python` or `python -V` and you will see the version of Python installed and now you should not get `Python 3.6.5`
4. Assuming that it worked correctly you will want to set up git bash so that it always knows where to find python. To do that, enter the following command: `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/d/Python36"' > .bashrc`

**Permanent Solution**

5. Go to BASH RC Source File (located on C: / C Drive in “C:\Users\myname”)
6. Make sure your BASH RC Source File is receiving direction from your Bash Profile Source File, you can do this by making sure that your BASH RC Source File contains this line of code:  source ~/.bash_profile
7. Go to BASH Profile Source File (located on C: / C Drive in “C:\Users\myname”)
8. Enter line: export PATH="$PATH:/D/PROGRAMMING/Applications/PYTHON/Python365" (assuming this is the location where Python version 3.6.5 is installed)
9. This should take care of the problem permanently.  Now whenever you open your Git Bash Terminal Prompt and enter “`python`” or “`python -V`” it should return the python version

Answer (score 3):

When you install python for windows, there is an option to include it in the path. For python 2 this is not the default. It adds the python installation folder and script folder to the Windows path. When starting the GIT Bash command prompt, it have included it in the linux PATH variable.

If you start the python installation again, you should select the option Change python and in the next step you can "Add python.exe to Path". Next time you open GIT Bash, the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This works great on win7

$ PATH=$PATH:/c/Python27/
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in you `.bashrc file`

```
############################
# Environment path setting #
############################
export PATH=/c/Python27:/c/Python27/Scripts:$PATH
```

Comment: Yes, thank you I had created a .bashrc file in my C:\Users<imID>\. I deleted it and restarted GitBash and commands started working again. Not sure who downvoted this but appreciate you not deleting this!

Answer (score 0):

Tried multiple of these, I switched to Cygwin instead which fixed python and some other problems I was having on Windows:

https://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

This way works on my **Windows 11** and **Windows 10**.
There are only 3 steps to solve this problem.

---

- 1. Find your `python.exe` file
- 2. set up your PATH in `~/.bashrc`
- 3. Restart your `Git Bash`, and you can use python

*The following will explain how to do each step in detail.*

---

### 1. Find your python.exe

$ `find /c/ | grep python.exe$ --color`

You will see a red color with `python.exe` if you ever install Python.
If you cannot see any red color for `python.exe`, you can
go to https://www.python.org/downloads/ to install.

In my example, I can find out this.
`/c/Users/MiloChen/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe`

---

### 2. Set up my PATH in ~/.bashrc

Use your editor to edit the file `~/.bashrc` (I can use VSCode or Vim)
There is no file in ~/.bashrc in default, if you cannot find this file, just create it.
Here is my result of ~/.bashrc
$ cat ~/.bashrc

```bash
export PATH=/c/Users/MiloChen/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/:$PATH
```

---

### 3. Restart your `Git Bash`, and you can use python

$ `which python`
/c/Users/MiloChen/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python

$ `python --version`
Python 3.11.5

The above is my result. It works.
When you restart Git Bash, it will load the ~/.bashrc by default.
So the PATH is ready to use the python in default when you restart Git Bash.

---

Answer (score 0):

I also can't run python from git bash, but get a different error. Permission denied.

However, I think I have found the problem. I can see it from all three places powershell cmd prompt and git bash and it's correct in the default location /c/Users/Username/AppData/local/WindowsApps/python, and that's the correct version, but it only runs from powershell and cmd prompt. The git bash gives me permission denied when I try to run it, and I believe that's because git bash is a 32 bit app and the python I installed was 64 bit.I never installed 32 bit python.

Changing permissions didn't work either.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35521971)