# Python starts extremely slowly the first time after I reboot Windows

Tags: python, windows, performance, profiling

I apologize for not having a reproducible example.  My problem is with a large base of proprietary code and I don't have an extract that shows the same behavior.  Even better, it isn't my software and I know about 2% of how it works.

Simply, this Python program I'm dealing with takes about 80 seconds to complete its entire setup and get to the point where all its flask code is running and the webserver being created is up and able to respond to requests.  BUT -- that's only the first time I run it on Windows after rebooting.  On subsequent times starting the python script in question, it takes more like 10 seconds.

And the nutty part is, in a workgroup of 10 people, mine is the only computer that has the problem.

Things I can say:

1. Python 2.7.11, Windows 7, git bash version 2.9.0.windows.1.
2. It doesn't appear to matter whether I invoke my python program from the git bash command line or the Windows command line.
3. However, in git bash, saying "python" gets no response forever until I hit Ctrl-C, but saying "winpty python" opens an interactive python session as it should.  I mention this because for a while I thought my main problem was related to the git bash shell bug (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599341/5593532).  But point 2 above would seem to contradict this. No such weirdness occurs in invoking a bare python interactive session from the Windows command line.
4. I've had trouble getting meaningful profiling output, partly because of multi-threading or child processes or something.  And the web server doesn't have an exit event per se, thus I can only stop it by smacking it with a Ctrl-C in the command-line window where I ran the script, which seems to kill the part of the process that would save the profiling data.
5. From the fragmentary profiling info I was able to produce (with gratitude to https://ymichael.com/2014/03/08/profiling-python-with-cprofile.html), I am suspicious that something weird is happening in loading a large number of imported packages, and perhaps especially the alembic and/or werkzeug packages.  (And maybe even sqlalchemy.)  The profiling output didn't have much tottime in those packages, but it did have rather a lot of cumtime there.
6. My sys.path inside Python doesn't seem meaningfully different from anyone else's nearby.  I might have one or two different items in the list, or three .egg files on the path when they've only got one, but it's mostly the same list in the same order.  So much for the idea that it's taking a long time to hunt and learn where packages are and then re-using the information later.
7. I've got PyCharm Community Edition able to run the script and its associated junk in IDE mode, set breakpoints, and all that jazz, so I can set breakpoints and follow execution to a degree, in case that would answer a noteworthy question you could raise for me.

Anyone got a wild notion what's up?  (he asked quite unreasonably)

Comment: Have you tried comparing your Python setup to everybody else's in your group. That is, everyone who also runs windows? Perhaps  there is something different about your Python setup than everyone else's.

Comment: badly configured antivirus software on your computer?