# Bash freezes when calling Ipython

Tags: python, bash, windows-10, ipython

I'm running windows 10 build 16193, using linux sub-systems for windows.

Only on this PC does this error happen. 
When I invoke `ipython`, it'll run, showing the expected text and will wait for input. From there on out, it will respond no further.

The same happens when i run `python manage.py shell` which runs the same interpreter as `ipython` (at least visually)

Comment: If none of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash work, [edit] the question to specify that ("I tried existing answer-X and it did A, I tried answer-Y and it did B") and I'll reopen. However, I'd be *very* unsurprised if [calling through winpty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599341/14122) did in fact resolve the issue.

Comment: Python is working fine. That's not my question. The `ipython` interpreter is not. Would the same solutions be applicable?

Comment: Same solutions can reasonably be expected to apply, yes. If those solutions don't work, specify that you tried them in the question.