# How to run npm scripts with WinPTY?

Tags: windows, npm, git-bash

I had the known issue of [python freezing in Git bash on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash). Many answers on stackoverflow suggested to use [WinPTY](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/).

Which works fine when I use:

`winpty python foo.py`

But I run a python program as part of a npm script. My package.json has this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "python foo.py && something else"
}
```

So I figure I will need to run npm script with WinPTY too:

`winpty npm start`

But this is not working. I got different error messages on different environments.

1. I got "Not found in PATH" at work which has latest git and npm installed, but *it is* in PATH:

> winpty: error: cannot start 'npm': Not found in PATH

2. I got a different error at my personal computer with a slightly older git:

> Error 0x2 starting npm start

Any ideas why npm and winpty isn't working together?

If I run `npm start` without winpty it works fine. `winpty node` works too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the same problem.
Actually, in nodejs installation folder, there is npm.cmd
So what you should do to start npm using winpty is

```
winpty npm.cmd install
```

Comment: for my own reference in 3-6 months `env PYTHON=/c/Python27/ winpty npm.cmd install` is the full command to also change the default python so that node-gyp works.