# I can't open a python file in git bash

Tags: python-3.x, file, git-bash

I'm trying to open a `.py` file on git bash but it doesn't work.

I have tried to follow some instructions like running `python <filename>` but it doesn't work for me.

When I run

> python python_basics

I expect it will open the `.py` file but it says it can't open file 'python_basics':

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: If the file is called `python_basics.py` then you must call `python python_basics.py`.

Comment: oh when i do like u said,nothing happen,even it doesn't pop any issue, it just show ~$ like normal

Comment: What should it do instead? Is `python_basics.py` supposed to generate some output?

Comment: yeah,it will pop up some statements/expressions for me to enter the output of these to move on

Comment: Have you tried running `python python_basics.py` from Command Line or PowerShell? Also, what happens if you just run `python`(no arguments) in Git Bash? (I'm assuming you are running Windows since you use Git Bash.)

Comment: Could you show the code? Normally statements and expressions don't produce any output, the script will just run from start to finish and you won't see anything.

Comment: how to show the code?it is quite long,i take it from here to practice with python
https://cs61a.org/lab/lab00/
you can scroll down to the Doing the assignment part,it is supposed to be just like that i think

Comment: can you guys help me :(  i really want to learn python,i'm now starting from zero

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python not working in the command line of git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash), the problem may very well be caused by Git Bash itself.

I would recommend you try running your Python file from a different terminal (`Command Prompt` or `PowerShell` if you are using Windows), using the command suggested in the comments:

> python python_basics.py

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, I am here to help you and who will see this question.

if you mean you want to open the file like when click on the file and open it
you can use this `command`

```
Start filename.py
```

but if you want to open the file inside the gitbash use this `command`

```
vim filename.py
```

and if you mean to run the file from gitbash you can use this `command`

```
python pythonFileName.py
```

**Now if the above command did not work with you, and you are in the windows10 Pro platform you should go to**

```
environment variable >> Then system variable >> then choose path >> then Edit >> and put the python path >> restart the terminal and run it again
```

Notice: All of the above I tried and used in windows10 pro.

Thanks,

Hope to help anyone,

Answer (score -1):

First check the python version installed on your system.
by command-
python --version.
If not found
set
$ PATH=$PATH:/c/Python27/

Adapting the path will solve your problem.

Comment: i have checked and it show Python 3.7.3,nothing went wrong

Comment: i have set it from the beginning