# How to edit Python path - I think I accidentally changed it after installing Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, path, environment-variables

I am extremely new to coding. I have been completing a Udemy course and everything has been going smoothly until I installed Visual Studio (as per the course instruction), however, I think I change the python path during the installation/setup of Visual Studio.

I don't really know how this works, but is it the case that I changed the path (from the one during the python installation process) to a different path associated with Visual Studio? I remember clicking/accepting something to do with PATH on Visual Studio, and now when following the course structure and trying to run the code from Visual Studio on Git Bash, I am hit with the:

"Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases."

I have troubleshooted to 'environment variables', but I am not grasping how to perform the edit so that the python path is back to how it was.

I have two paths it seems:

1. C:\Users********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\

and

2. C:\Users********\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\

I don't quite understand how the 'move up' and 'move down' functions work.

Could somebody please put this n00b out of their misery. Please XD

Answer (score 0):

these two paths are coreect you dont have to edit these. when you install python these two paths qre added to your envirnoment variables path

Comment: Hmm. Okay.

Well, I am trying to run a python file in Git Bash using 'python3 blockchain.py' and it is giving me the message that Python was not found. I am not sure what cmd/program the Udemy guy is using, he is using a Mac, and he isn't very forthcoming with information.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash)  you should check this. it may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check in the bottom left corner, you'll have this option. Select the python interpreter from the dropdown.

Also check if you've correctly installed python, by typing `python --version` in the cmd.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So.. another n00b question. What are you running? What toolbar is that? I don't have that. I used the 'python --version' and I have Python 3.9.5

Comment: I'm using VS code, and that toolbar is present in vs code by default. You should uninstall vs code, and do a fresh reinstall. Do as it is shown in the following link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial.