# Installing Django Error

Tags: python, django, cmd

I am trying to install Django by using a tutorial.([tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIVwVOpwpsA).)

I download the latest release (1.6.2) and untar(unzip) it.

Then I open the file that contains Django on my Desktop and copy the Directory.

I open the command prompt.

From `C:\Users\Name\Desktop>` I type `cd` and I paste the Directory.

This opens the Django directory which is `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Django-1.6.2`

Inside this file there is a `setup.py` file.

**According to the tutorial** if I type `python setup.py install` it will install Django for me! And this actually happens in the tutorial video but not in my case!!!

When I type it gives me the following:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

If I go into the Django file and `Double-click` the `setup.py` file I momentarily see in the window (before it closes) `error: no commands supplied`

What must I do? I am trying to install Django for 2 days now and it is getting really frustrating.

---

## SOLVED

Must set Path Variable from Environmental Variables FIRST!

For a quick solution, look at the answer + [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7) and choose melhosseiny's answer.

Comment: As the video says in the desription: `This assumes that you've already got python installed.`. Since you get the error that `Python` is not available you should install it ;)

Comment: Go to Environment variables and add the path to python.exe to the `PATH` variable. ADD, don't replace or you'll mess up your other programs.

Comment: @Wolph i have python 2.7 installed

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant What's the Windows path where you have Python installed?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu i will now tried what you have told me and nothing happended :-(

Comment: `C:\Python27` is the directory of the python

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `C:\Python27\python setup.py install`

Additionally, if you don't want to add `C:\Python27\` to all of your python commands, you need to add it to your Windows Path. This can be done by going to your environment variables and add `C:\Python27` (notice the lack of a trailing slash) to the PATH variable. Make sure you are adding to, not replacing, the values there are present.

Comment: Do i need to omit the trailing slash on the Environmental Variable Path? I did not. I typed in the `Path` variable case sensitive the directory: `;C:\Python27`

Comment: IT WORKS! People that make tutorials for ultra beginners MUST have these stuff in the tutorial! Thanks a million!