# How to install Pyside for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, qt5, pyside

Hey I am pretty new to Pyside and am not sure how to download it or Qt? I have a 64-bit Windows computer and am wondering what I need to download once I have downloaded Qt because there is a checklist for like Qt 5.3, Qt 5.2.1, etc. and I am not sure which to download because under those there are multiple options under them like MSCV2012 64-bit and mscv64-bit OpenGL. Basically I am just very lost on what I need and can't seem to find the answer. Could someone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyside You can download install files from here.

Answer (score 18):

Install pip:

1. Download pip installer from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and save it in a directory other than C.
2. If you haven't set your python path: follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-path-on-windows-7).
3. Open Command Prompt and cd to that directory where you saved the pip installer.
4. run: `python get-pip.py`

Install pyside:

1. Close and Reopen Command Prompt.
2. run: `cd C:\Python27\Scripts`
3. run: `pip install -U PySide`

Comment: I opened the Command Prompt and cd'ed to that directory where I saved the pip installer, but there was no file there named "get-pip.py", and so the command "python get-pip.py" failed.   Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @user235218, The download link provided in the answer was outdated. I updated the answer with a new download link to the pip installer.

Answer (score 3):

[PySide](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide) does not yet support the Qt 5.x branch.

Simply running `pip install pyside` will install bindings that support the Qt 4.8 branch. Thus, you need that version of Qt.

Comment: Ok thank you! But with that said what Qt version should I download for Python 2.7?

Comment: You don't need to download and install standalone Qt distribution. PySide binaries are independent and already contains all required Qt libraries, devel tools and examples.

Answer (score 0):

All the steps are mentioned [in here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows), but for your convenience, here goes it inline:

> Installing prerequisites
>
> Install latest pip distribution: download get-pip.py [bootstrap.pypa.io] and run it using the python interpreter.
>   Installing PySide on a Windows System
>
> To install PySide on Windows you can choose from the following options:

```
Use pip [pypi.python.org] to install the wheel binary packages by issuing the command:
    pip install -U PySide
Use setuptools [pypi.python.org] to install the egg binary packages by issuing the command (deprecated):
    easy_install -U PySide
Download and install the packages from the PyPI page [pypi.python.org]
```

> Provided binaries are without any other external dependencies. All required Qt libraries, development tools and examples are included.

Then, you can grab the Qt 4.8.6 version from here:

http://qt-project.org/downloads

Please note that there is no installer for VS2012 off-hand, so you should use an older version or mingw. Alternatively, you could also build Qt 4 yourself.

Comment: The answer is correct, but incomplete: Provided (PySide) binaries are without any other external dependencies. All required Qt libraries, development tools and examples are included - That means you don't need to install Qt - it is already included in PySide distribution.